# How to add a button on unity panel (from Nautilus's bookmarks)?

Tags: unity, nautilus, panel, bookmarks

Is there a way to make a launcher (icon) on Unity panel from Nautilus's bookmarks or it is for programs only?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script to do that autmatically. See:

[What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/43150#43150)

> ## Home Icon Quicklist (auto-update from bookmarks)
>
> Here is a small shell script that updates
>   your Home-Quicklist with all your
>   nautilus bookmarks.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to only be for Programs at this point, I've just made a custom launcher and set it to Location and entered the command so it would open up where I wanted it to, then I went into Terminal and did gksudo nautilus and then navigated my way to home/username/Desktop and copied the launcher to usr/share/applications.  Then I dragged the launcher to unity but it didn't stay.

If you'd like to place icons in Unity, say for example Wine programs that you've installed then I have the following instructions for you.

1 - Right click your desktop

2 - Select **Create Launcher**

3 - Create the custom Launcher as you want to

Now you got the launcher on the Desktop. If you are satisfied with it, get it in the Launcher Panel:

4 - Open Nautilus as root. Press **Alt + F2** and paste **gksu nautilus**

5 - Browse to **/home/your-username/Desktop**

6 - Copy the launcher by clicking right on it and select Copy

7 - Browse to **/usr/share/applications**

8 - Paste your launcher by clicking right on a blank space and select Paste

9 - Now drag and drop your launcher from **/usr/share/applications** to the Launcher Bar on the left on your Screen

10 - You can now delete your custom Launcher on the Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you press super(winkey)+f or click "Files and folders" on your launcher, then Favorite folders are Nautilus bookmarks. If you want a menu in the notification area, then that's certainly possible to make, but I don't know of any existing ones. It should be fairly easy though.