# What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?

Tags: unity, launcher, quicklists

> **Please note that right now, most of the information contained below is outdated and cannot be updated. Be careful, most of this won't work on Ubuntu 12.04 and newer.**

Creating a custom launcher for Unity is simple. Quicklists provide an easy and efficient way to quickly access commonly used tasks for a specific application.

**NOTE:** Starting with Ubuntu 11.10, this popup option has vanished. Launchers can now only be created by editing text files in your home folder.

Creating a custom launcher is easy.

1. Right-click on your desktop and click create a launcher.
2. Edit the .desktop file using a text editor. (More information can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32991/how-do-i-add-a-static-quicklist-that-opens-a-web-page).)

**So, which custom launchers do you use on Unity?**

*Note: Please limit yourself to one custom launcher per answer. Also, please provide a screenshot of it in action.*

Answer (score 68):

## Home Icon Quicklist

[image: Home Icon Quicklist]

1. Copy 'Home Folder' launcher file to your home directory:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.local/share/applications
   cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the file for editing in gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop
   ```
3. **Delete** the following line from the file:

   ```
   OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
   ```
4. **Add** this text to the **bottom** of the file, then close and save:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Videos;Documents;Music;Pictures;Downloads
   [Videos Shortcut Group]
   Name=Videos
   Exec=nautilus Videos
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Documents Shortcut Group]
   Name=Documents
   Exec=nautilus Documents
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Music Shortcut Group]
   Name=Music
   Exec=nautilus Music
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Pictures Shortcut Group]
   Name=Pictures
   Exec=nautilus Pictures
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Downloads Shortcut Group]
   Name=Downloads
   Exec=nautilus Downloads
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
5. Log out and log in again to see the changes.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35024/how-to-add-my-favorite-places-as-a-quicklist-in-my-homes-icon-in-unity)

Comment: Is there any way to add a quicklist item for connecting to a server over ssh in nautilus?

Comment: it seems that this only works with english locales, or at least it does not work for me (german)

Comment: @marto Good Comment!! This is can be rectified by making a small modification....you have to add " Name[de] = the german translation"....and do this for each command.

Comment: @marto create a new askubuntu question as this might be popular

Comment: Make sure the OnlyShowIn line lists Unity: `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;`  This didn't work for me until I caught this, since my original file only listed GNOME.

Comment: @keithjgrant didn't work for me too; I edited the missing part.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/43150#43150 for the same with auto-update from nautilus bookmarks

Comment: There is an auto-updating quicklist for nautilus below

Comment: If "OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;" line is not removed your "Home Folder Launcher Icon" will only launch the app, not control it (http://youtu.be/oS52pYNFZ6I). A 2nd icon will show up that does the controlling part. I learnt it the hard way, Until this set me right http://askubuntu.com/questions/35024/how-to-add-my-favorite-places-as-a-quicklist-in-my-homes-icon-in-unity

Answer (score 49):

## SSH Launcher

Access of list of your favorite SSH servers quickly.

[image: ssh quicklist]

1. **Create a new file with gedit, in the [Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal/38220) type:**

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/ssh-launcher.desktop
   ```
2. **Copy & Paste** this text into the above file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Remote Servers
   Comment=Login to my servers
   Exec=gnome-terminal --disable-factory --sm-client-disable --class=remoteserver -x ssh -t minibox.local 
   Terminal=false
   X-MultipleArgs=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=utilities-terminal
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=RemoteServers
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Server1;

   [Server1 Shortcut Group]
   Name=SSH into minibox.local
   Exec=gnome-terminal --disable-factory --sm-client-disable  --class=remoteserver -x ssh -t minibox.local
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   Comment=You can create more of these. Just add to X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts a "Server2", "Server3" etc, then change the domain name (in this case, "minibox.local") to the name of your server. You'll also notice that the default action (When you just click the icon in the launcher) is to SSH into minibox.local - you'll need to change that to your most used server.
   ```
3. **Drag and Drop** onto the launcher by navigating to
   ~/.local/share/applications/ in
   Nautilus.

[Source 1](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jamesgifford/unity-quicklist-examples/trunk/files), [Source 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34597/how-do-i-make-a-custom-launcher-for-terminal-applications)

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/44657#44657 to update automatically from `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: This one doesn't actually work properly currently. The gnome-terminal windows appear under the normal gnome-terminal launcher icon instead of the ssh-launcher one. This only happens if you launch your first remote connection from the quicklist. If you open one with left click it works correctly, and all subsequent windows also work correctly.

Answer (score 47):

## Ubuntu Software Center Quicklist

Quickly add PPAs through the software-properties UI and update sources as well.

[image: Software manager quicklist]

1. **Copy** the original .desktop file to your home folder using [Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal/38220):

   `cp /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-software-center.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`
2. **Open the file** for editing with gedit:

   `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/ubuntu-software-center.desktop`
3. Add the following at the **bottom** of the file. This should be entered after the line *X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=software-center*

.

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=SoftwareUpdates;SoftwareProperties;Synaptic;

[SoftwareUpdates Shortcut Group]  
Name=Update Manager  
Exec=update-manager -c  
OnlyShowIn=Unity

[SoftwareProperties Shortcut Group]  
Name=Add/Edit PPAs  
Exec=gksu software-properties-gtk %u  
OnlyShowIn=Unity

[Synaptic Shortcut Group]  
Name=Synaptic Software Manager  
Exec=gksu synaptic %u  
OnlyShowIn=Unity
```

Comment: this is great!!

Comment: Cool - presumably you could add a line to launch Synaptic as well if you want a bit more control?  It looks like I should just be able to follow your pattern.

Comment: :).. yes.. the latest update of this code has it!. Try out Easylinux OS at http://easylinuxos.sourceforge.net.

Comment: Guys, on last edit [SoftwareUpdates Shortcut Group] is not in the X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts line so "Update Manager" won't show in the list. Just in case others might get confused why it's missing the top entry.

Comment: I can confirm that this work in Oneiric 11.10.

Answer (score 42):

## Home Icon Quicklist (auto-update from bookmarks)

Here is a small shell script that updates your Home-Quicklist with all your bookmarks. No manual manipulation. It reads your bookmark file and creates the menu items from it. It also adds the "Root Filemanager" menu entry.

[image: Screenshot of the quicklist in action]

1. Copy the script listed below into an empty file and put it in your scripts-folder (we will assume that is `~/bin/` and the script name you choose is `unityhome.bash`).
2. Run the script once to add the entries:

   ```
   bash ~/bin/unityhome.bash
   ```
3. Optionally you may have cron run the script for you every once in a while. To add it to cron, type the follwing command into a shell:

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```

   An editor will open. There add a line like:

   ```
   @reboot /bin/bash/ $HOME/bin/unityhome.bash > /dev/null 2>&1
   ```

   If you don't do this step, you'll have to run the script by hand every time you change your nautilus bookmarks if you want the quicklist updated.
4. Changes only take effect on your next login or after you Alt+F2

   ```
   unity --replace
   ```

   So do that. *Note: Don't run `unity --replace` in a terminal. If you close that terminal, it will kill unity with it.*
5. Enjoy and have a look at the [similar script for gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/44657#44657) that parses your ssh bookmarks (in `~/.ssh/config`).

### Script:

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# tabsize: 4, encoding: utf8
#
# © 2011 con-f-use@gmx.net. Use permitted under MIT license:
#     http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
# 
# CONTRIBUTORS: Chris Druif <cyber.druif@gmail.com>
#               Scott Severance <http://www.scottseverance.us/>
#               jacopoL <jacopo.jl@gmail.com>
# 
# This script updates the unity quicklist menu for nautilus to contain the user
# bookmarks. The updates will have efect after unity is restarted (either on
# the next login or by invoking 'unity --replace').

# location of template and unity bar launchers
nautempl="/usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop"
target="$HOME/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop"
bookmarks="$HOME/.gtk-bookmarks"

# backup if file already exists
if [ -e "$target" ]; then
    echo "Creating backup of: $target."
    mv -n "$target" "$target.bak"
fi

# copy template
cp "$nautempl" "$target"

if ! grep -q 'OnlyShowIn=.*Unity' "$target"; then # add only if not already present
    sed -i "s/\(OnlyShowIn=.*\)/\1Unity;/" "$target"
fi

# due to a bug in Unity (Ubuntu 11.10+) we will have to completely remove the OnlyShowIn line:
# https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/842257/comments/6
sed -i '/^OnlyShowIn=/d' "$target"

if ! grep -q 'X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=' "$target"; then # add only if not already present
    echo -e "\nX-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=\n" >> "$target"
else
    echo >> "$target"
fi
bmcount=0
while read bmline; do
    bmcount=$(($bmcount+1))     # number of current bookmark
    bmname=${bmline#*\ }        # name of the bookmark
    bmpath=${bmline%%\ *}       # path the bookmark leads to
    # deal with bookmarks that have no name
    if [ "$bmname" = "$bmpath" ]; then
        bmname=${bmpath##*/}
    fi
    # fix spaces in names and paths
    bmname="$(echo "$bmname" | sed 's/%20/ /g')"
    bmpath="$(echo "$bmpath" | sed 's/%20/ /g')"
    # fix accents in names and paths (for french users)
    bmname="$(echo "$bmname" | python -c 'import sys,urllib;sys.stdout.write(urllib.unquote(sys.stdin.read()))')"
    bmpath="$(echo "$bmpath" | python -c 'import sys,urllib;sys.stdout.write(urllib.unquote(sys.stdin.read()))')"
    # extend shortcut list with current bookmark, prepending a ; if needed
    sed -i "s/\(X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=\(.*;$\|$\)\)/\1Scg${bmcount};/
            t
            s/\(X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=.*\)/\1;Scg${bmcount};/" "$target"
    # write bookmark information
    cat - >> "$target" <<EOF

[Scg$bmcount Shortcut Group]
Name=$bmname
Exec=nautilus "$bmpath"
TargetEnvironment=Unity
EOF
done < "$bookmarks"

# Add a root file manager entry
sed -i "s/\(X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=.*\)/\1RootFM;/" "$target"
cat - >> "$target" <<EOF

[RootFM Shortcut Group]
Name=Root
Exec=gksudo nautilus
TargetEnvironment=Unity
EOF

exit 0
```

### Improvement: Do not duplicate "Home folder" and "username"

If you don't want to have two items targeting your Home folder ("Home Folder" at the bottom of the quicklist and the clickable username), you can replace the following code:

```
    # write bookmark information
    cat - >> "$target" <<EOF

[Scg$bmcount Shortcut Group]
Name=$bmname
Exec=nautilus "$bmpath"
TargetEnvironment=Unity
EOF
done < "$bookmarks"
```

by the following code:

```
    # write bookmark information
    if [ "file://$HOME" != "$bmpath" ]; then
    cat - >> "$target" <<EOF

[Scg$bmcount Shortcut Group]
Name=$bmname
Exec=nautilus "$bmpath"
TargetEnvironment=Unity
EOF
    fi
done < "$bookmarks"
```

Comment: Basically the same thing exists as an indicator applet for unity: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators/42432#42432

Comment: Don't forget to go to ~/.local/share/applications to drag the file nautilus-home.desktop to the Unity bar.

Comment: This script also works for Thunar. Just replace on top `nautilus-home.desktop` with `Thunar.desktop` and all the way down `gksudo nautilus` by `gksudo thunar`

Comment: This script can now handle names and paths that contain spaces.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, and I have a little request to make it even better (for me, at least): Is it possible to set your quicklist to NOT open a new icon on the Launcher? One is perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I'm not quite sure what you mean by "open a new icon".

Comment: Note that a similar quicklist is now included in 12.04 by default.

Answer (score 38):

## LibreOffice Quicklist

This creates a quicklist for the LibreOffice Start Center launcher.

[image: LibreOffice Quicklist]

1. Copy your original .desktop file into your home directory for editing:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-startcenter.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open in gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-startcenter.desktop
   ```
3. Edit the MimeType line:

   *Find* the following line:

   ```
   MimeType=application/vnd.openofficeorg.extension;
   ```

   *Replace* with:

   ```
   MimeType=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master;application/vnd.sun.xml.writer;application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template;application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global;application/vnd.stardivision.writer;application/msword;application/vnd.ms-word;application/x-doc;application/rtf;text/rtf;application/vnd.wordperfect;application/wordperfect;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template;application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template;application/vnd.sun.xml.calc;application/vnd.sun.xml.calc.template;application/vnd.stardivision.calc;application/vnd.stardivision.chart;application/msexcel;application/vnd.ms-excel;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template;application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12;text/csv;application/x-dbf;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template;application/vnd.sun.xml.draw;application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template;application/vnd.stardivision.draw;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template;application/vnd.sun.xml.impress;application/vnd.sun.xml.impress.template;application/vnd.stardivision.impress;application/mspowerpoint;application/vnd.ms-powerpoint;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation;application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template;application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula;application/vnd.sun.xml.math;application/vnd.stardivision.math;
   ```
4. Highlight and copy the text below,
   then paste it at the **bottom** of
   the .desktop file:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Writer;Impress;Calc;Math;Draw

   [Writer Shortcut Group]
   Name=Writer
   Exec=libreoffice -writer %U
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Impress Shortcut Group]
   Name=Impress
   Exec=libreoffice -impress %U
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Calc Shortcut Group]
   Name=Calc
   Exec=libreoffice -calc %U
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Math Shortcut Group]
   Name=Math
   Exec=libreoffice -math %U
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Draw Shortcut Group]
   Name=Draw
   Exec=libreoffice -draw %U
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

   **Note**: **For LibreOffice 3.4 and 3.4.1:** in Exec; `libreoffice` must be replaced with `libreoffice3.4', but it seems in Oneiric we don't need to add the version number. I'm testing it from Oneiric and leaving default just run well, adding the verison number make the quicklist unusable
5. Navigate to ~/.local/share/applications and drag'n'drop the LibreOffice Start Center desktop file onto the launcher.

A similar modification can be made to the LibreOffice [Writer](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/how-to-add-folder-quicklists-to-the-home-launcher-in-ubuntu-unity/#comment-189776441) launcher.

[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/how-to-unity-quicklists-for-libreoffice-gmail-and-chromium/)

Comment: I have added the dragndrop support as outlined [below](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/42269#42269)

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works on LibreOffice 3.4

Comment: **For LibreOffice 3.4 and 3.4.1:**  in Exec; `libreoffice` must be replaced with `libreoffice3.4` .

Answer (score 32):

## Firefox Quicklist

Add handy Firefox options to the launcher.

[image]

1. **Copy** your original .desktop file into your home directory for editing:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. **Open** in gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
   ```
3. **Find and edit** the following line:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;
   ```

   to match this line:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;SafeMode;ProfileManager;
   ```
4. **Add** this text to the **bottom** of the .desktop, then save the file:

   ```
   [SafeMode Shortcut Group]
   Name=Open Firefox in safe mode
   Exec=firefox -safe-mode
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [ProfileManager Shortcut Group]
   Name=Firefox Profile Manager
   Exec=firefox -ProfileManager
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

Comment: Firefox launcher is a bit "buggy" on my end. Does this happen to others? Editing it's .desktop file will not update the changes in real-time unlike the others. If you want to see the changes, close FF, remove from launcher and drag the edited .desktop file above to the launcher. Sometimes that action will cause a weird behavior in that even if FF is running, it will not reflect in the launcher. Quick fix is to logout/in.

Answer (score 32):

## Terminal Quicklist

[image: terminal img (updated)]

1. **Copy** original Terminal launcher into your home directory using [Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal/38220):

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. **Open the file** with gedit still using Terminal:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
   ```
3. **Find** the following line from the file:

   ```
   OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
   ```

   **Replace** the above line with:

   ```
   OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
   ```
4. Add this text to the **bottom** of the file then **Save & Close** it:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;NewTab;Top;Root;

   [NewWindow Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Window
   Exec=gnome-terminal --window
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [NewTab Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Tab
   Exec=xdotool windowfocus gnome-terminal key ctrl+shift+t
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Root Shortcut Group]
   Name=Root Terminal
   Exec=gksudo gnome-terminal
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Top Shortcut Group]
   Name=Top
   Exec=gnome-terminal --command top
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
5. To enable the 'New Tab' option you need to install [`xdotool`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool)
   [image: Install xdotool] from Ubuntu Software Centre
6. Close all Terminal windows, right-click on its launcher icon and untick 'Keep In Launcher'
7. Open Dash, run `Terminal` and the new launcher with quicklist will appear.

Comment: the new tab shorcut form me open a new window. the command is correct...

Comment: @Cas: I've got the same problem, so I'll look into a solution.

Comment: Did some testing and it seems to be the fault of gnome-terminal itself.

Comment: I've found the solution by using a bash script and xdotool :D I am just testing it and then will add instructions.

Comment: @Cas: \o/ sweet!

Comment: @Roland Taylor: Fixed, no need for bash script afterall :P

Answer (score 31):

## Google Services Launcher

A custom launcher for common services like gmail, calendar, composing a new message.

[image]

1. **Create a new file** by opening Text Editor and paste the following text into it:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Google Services
   Exec=xdg-open https://accounts.google.com/
   Terminal=false
   X-MultipleArgs=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=chrome-https___docs.google.com_
   Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=docs.google.com

   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Plus;Inbox;Compose;Voice;Contacts;Calendar;Documents;Photos;Maps;Sites;Reader;Bookmarks
   Name[en_US]=Google Services (Gmail)
   [Plus Shortcut Group]
   Name=Plus
   Exec=xdg-open 'https://plus.google.com/u/0/'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Inbox Shortcut Group]
   Name=InBox
   Exec=xdg-open 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Compose Shortcut Group]
   Name=Compose
   Exec=xdg-open 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#compose'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Voice Shortcut Group]
   Name=Voice
   Exec=xdg-open 'https://www.google.com/voice/b/0?pli=1#inbox'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Contacts Shortcut Group]
   Name=Contacts
   Exec=xdg-open 'https://www.google.com/contacts'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Calendar Shortcut Group]
   Name=Calendar
   Exec=xdg-open 'https://calendar.google.com'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Documents Shortcut Group]
   Name=Documents
   Exec=xdg-open https://docs.google.com/
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Photos Shortcut Group]
   Name=Photos
   Exec=xdg-open 'https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Maps Shortcut Group]
   Name=Maps
   Exec=xdg-open 'http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=ml'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Sites Shortcut Group]
   Name=Sites
   Exec=xdg-open 'https://sites.google.com/?tab=m3&pli=1'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Reader Shortcut Group]
   Name=Reader
   Exec=xdg-open 'https://www.google.com/reader/view/?hl=en&tab=my'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [Bookmarks Shortcut Group]
   Name=Bookmarks
   Exec=xdg-open 'https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
2. **Save the file** with this folder location and name:

   ```
    ~/.local/share/applications/google-services-launcher.desktop
   ```
3. **Drag and Drop** this file onto the launcher by navigating to
   `~/.local/share/applications/` in
   File Manager.

You can download the icon [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4697206/Google.tar.gz).

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32991/how-do-i-add-a-static-quicklist-that-opens-a-web-page)

Comment: Why does it use google-chrome? I guess it would be better to use the default browser, by executing `gnome-www-browser link`

Comment: This is a google chrome desktop app just for checking mail and calendar. You can of course create a .desktop shortcut to launch these services in the default browser.

Answer (score 25):

## Banshee Quicklist

[image: banshee quicklist]

1. Copy the Banshee launcher to your home directory, in Terminal paste the following:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/banshee.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open this new file for editing:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/banshee.desktop
   ```
3. Highlight and copy the text below, then paste this at the **bottom** of the file.

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play;Pause;Stop;Previous;Next;Preferences

   [Play Shortcut Group]
   Name=Play
   Exec=banshee --play
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Pause Shortcut Group]
   Name=Pause
   Exec=banshee --pause
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Stop Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop
   Exec=banshee --stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Previous Shortcut Group]
   Name=Previous
   Exec=banshee --previous
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Next Shortcut Group]
   Name=Next
   Exec=banshee --next
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Preferences Shortcut Group]
   Name=Preferences
   Exec=banshee --show-preferences
   TargetEnviroment=Unity
   ```

Sources: [1](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jamesgifford/unity-quicklist-examples/trunk/files), [2](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/how-to-add-a-banshee-quicklist-for-easy-music-control-in/)

Comment: I don't see much point in this, we have the Sound menu!

Answer (score 24):

### Google Docs Quicklist

[image]

1. Create a new file with this command:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gdocs.desktop
   ```
2. Paste in the text below:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Google Docs
   Exec=xdg-open https://docs.google.com/
   Terminal=false
   X-MultipleArgs=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=chrome-https___docs.google.com_
   Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=docs.google.com

   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Doc;Spreadsheet;Presentation;Drawing

   [Doc Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Document
   Exec=xdg-open https://docs.google.com/?action=newdoc
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Spreadsheet Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Spreadsheet
   Exec=xdg-open https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?new
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Presentation Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Presentation
   Exec=xdg-open https://docs.google.com/?action=new_presentation
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Drawing Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Drawing
   Exec=xdg-open https://docs.google.com/drawings/create?hl=en
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

   > Note that this opens in your default
   >   browser. For chrome/ium fullscreen
   >   apps, find and replace `xdg-open` with
   >   `chromium-browser` and `https:` with
   >   `--app=https:`.
3. Drag the gdocs.desktop into the launcher from ~/.local/share/applications/

Comment: Works great! Except that the icon doesn't show up that nice, I just get a question mark in a square. What is needed to get a nice icon as well?

Comment: hmm i'm not sure... do you have chrome/ium installed? I copied the "Icon=" property from the chromium-generated launcher for google docs, so maybe it's dependent on that.

Comment: You can download either of [these](http://chromeunderground.blogspot.com/2011/02/google-docs-app.html) and point the "Icon=" field at the top of the launcher file to that file (/home/<user>/.icons/gdocs.png or whatever)

Answer (score 24):

## Quicklist to Add/Remove workspaces rows/columns

[image: Preview]

Easily add or remove virtual desktops or workspaces with a Unity icon/quicklist, an option sourly missed in Ubuntu currently. Only option seems to be going into gconf-editor and changing them manually.
Ideally this would make it's way into the Workspace Switcher.

It relies on a script to pull in the current number of rows and columns and add or subtracts one before setting it again. It also checks that it doesn't go below one row or column.

1. **Create a new .desktop file with gedit, in the [Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal/38220) type:**

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/workspaces.desktop
   ```
2. **Copy & Paste** this text into the newly created file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Workspaces
   Comment=Change Workspace Numbers
   GenericName=Workspace Editor
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=desktop
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=AddRow;RmRow;AddColumn;RmColumn;

   [AddRow Shortcut Group]
   Name=Add Row
   Exec=workspaces-shortcuts rows +
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [AddColumn Shortcut Group]
   Name=Add Column
   Exec=workspaces-shortcuts cols +
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [RmRow Shortcut Group]
   Name=Remove Row
   Exec=workspaces-shortcuts rows -
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [RmColumn Shortcut Group]
   Name=Remove Column
   Exec=workspaces-shortcuts cols -
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
3. **Create a new script with gedit, in the [Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal/38220) type:**

   ```
   gksudo gedit /usr/bin/workspaces-shortcuts
   ```

   NOTE: gksudo is used because of the location we'll be saving it and because it's a graphical application.
4. **Copy & Paste** this text into the newly created file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   case $1 in 
   rows)t=v;;
   cols)t=h;;
   esac;

   check=`gconftool-2 --get /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/${t}size`

   if [[ ! ($2 = - && $check < 2 ) ]]
   then
       [[ $2 = [-+] ]] && gconftool-2 --set /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/${t}size --type int $(( $check $2 1 ))
   fi
   ```
5. **Too make the script executable, in the [Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal/38220) type:**

   `sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/workspaces-shortcuts`
6. **Drag and Drop** onto the launcher by navigating to
   ~/.local/share/applications/ in
   Nautilus.

   Sorting can be easily done by changing in the .desktop-file the line from:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=AddRow;RmRow;AddColumn;RmColumn;
   ```

   to

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=AddRow;AddColumn;RmRow;RmColumn;
   ```

   for example.

Answer (score 23):

## Chromium Quicklist

[image: Chromium]

1. Copy the Chromium launcher to your home directory, in Terminal paste the following:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open this file for editing:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
   ```
3. Highlight and copy the text below, then paste it at the **bottom** of the file.

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;Incognito;

   [NewWindow Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Window
   Exec=chromium-browser
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Incognito Shortcut Group]
   Name=New incognito window
   Exec=chromium-browser --incognito
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

[Source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jamesgifford/unity-quicklist-examples/trunk/files)

Comment: For the record, Chromium packages from the [chromium-daily PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa) come with Unity quicklists preconfigured.

Comment: Also for the record; this is now in Chrome stable.

Answer (score 21):

## Filezilla FTP Quicklist

Quickly access your favourite FTP servers with from the Filezilla launcher.

[image: filezilla quicklist]

There is two options of making a FileZille quicklist. You can link to sites in the Site Manager (the safe option); or you can enter connection info directly in the `.desktop` file (the option without the Site Manager).

### Link to Site Manager (the safe option)

1. Copy the Filezilla launcher to your home directory, in Terminal paste the following:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/filezilla.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open this file for editing:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/filezilla.desktop
   ```
3. Append the text below at the **bottom** of the .desktop file, adding a "Shortcut Group" for each site you want to link. In the Exec parameter you should put the path of your FTP site in Site Manager. The 2° shortcut directly open the Filezilla Site Manager.

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Server1;sitemanager

   [Server1 Shortcut Group]
   Name=Site Name
   Exec=filezilla -c "0/Folder Name/Site Name"
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [sitemanager Shortcut Group]
   Name=Site Manager
   Exec=filezilla -s
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

For details, you should look at the [Command-line arguments](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_%28Client%29) page on Filezilla wiki.

[Source](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_%28Client%29)

---

### Directly enter connection details (the quick but unsafe option)

**Note: There is a security problem with this option** in that you *will* be storing your password ***in plain text***. Do this only if you know the risk, this is a very "hackish" way of doing things. If you use the Site Manager in FileZilla, *do use the option above* which uses the info already stored in Filezilla Site Manager configuration.

1. Copy the Filezilla launcher to your home directory, in Terminal paste the following:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/filezilla.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open this file for editing:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/filezilla.desktop
   ```
3. Highlight and copy the text below, then paste it at the **bottom** of the .desktop file. Edit the FTP server details to match your own, then save the file.

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Server1;

   [Server1 Shortcut Group]
   Name=FTP into test server 
   Exec=filezilla ftp://test:test@ftp.secureftp-test.com:21
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

   You'll want to change the "test:test" with your username/password respectively, and the "ftp.secureftp-test.com" with the domain of your ftp server.

[Source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jamesgifford/unity-quicklist-examples/trunk/view/head:/filezilla.desktop)

Comment: Merged in [the other FileZilla answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/63030#63030) to have the safer option getting more attention.

Answer (score 21):

## Gedit Quicklist

[image: gedit]

1. Copy 'Gedit' launcher file to your home directory using Terminal

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the file for editing in gedit :

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gedit.desktop
   ```
3. **Add** this text to the **bottom** of the file and **replace** the `<username>` text to match your home folder username then save & close:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=OpenDoc;OpenDocRoot;

   [OpenDoc Shortcut Group]
   Name=Open file...
   Exec=/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/scripts/gedit-shortcuts normal-mode
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [OpenDocRoot Shortcut Group]
   Name=Open file as root...
   Exec=/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/scripts/gedit-shortcuts root-mode
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. Create a 'scripts' folder in ~/.local/share/applications folder:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.local/share/applications/scripts
   ```
5. Create the script file 'gedit-shortcuts' with gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/scripts/gedit-shortcuts
   ```
6. Add this text to the file then save and close:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   case $1 in
   normal-mode) gedit $(zenity --title='Open file...' --file-selection);;
   root-mode) gksudo -u root -m "Running Gedit as user root allow you to modify some essential files of your system" "bash -c 'gedit \$(zenity --title=\'Open file as user root...\' --file-selection)'";;
   esac
   ```
7. Make the file executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/scripts/gedit-shortcuts
   ```
8. Drag & Drop the gedit.desktop file from ~/.local/share/applications in nautilus to the Unity Launcher Bar

Comment: Please test before posting instructions as there were errors in the desktop entry code.

Comment: Sorry I was not on my ubuntu machine but at work, so I wrote instruction with the remeber of what I did last night (so it's not a copy/paste) so maybe there were an error on one term or two :(

Answer (score 20):

### LAMP Quicklist

[image: Screenshot]

1. Open a new file:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/lamp.desktop
   ```
2. Copy the text below

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=LAMP
   GenericName=LAMP
   X-GNOME-FullName=LAMP
   Comment=Open services of your LAMP server
   Exec=gksu service apache2 start && gksu service mysql start
   Icon=emblem-web
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true

   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Start;Stop;Restart


   [Start Shortcut Group]
   Name=Start
   Exec=gksu service apache2 start && gksu service mysql start
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Stop Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop
   Exec=gksu service apache2 stop && gksu service mysql stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Restart Shortcut Group]
   Name=Restart
   Exec=gksu service apache2 restart && gksu service mysql restart
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
3. Drag and Drop onto the launcher by navigating to ~/.local/share/applications/ in Nautilus.

Answer (score 20):

### Rhythmbox Quicklist

[image: Screenshot]

1. Copy the Rhythmbox launcher to your home directory, in Terminal paste the following:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open this file for editing:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop
   ```
3. Highlight and copy the text below, then paste it at the bottom of the file:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play;Pause;Previous;Next;Stop

   [Play Shortcut Group]  
   Name=Play  
   Exec=rhythmbox-client --play  
   TargetEnvironment=Unity  

   [Pause Shortcut Group]  
   Name=Pause  
   Exec=rhythmbox-client --pause  
   TargetEnvironment=Unity  

   [Previous Shortcut Group]  
   Name=Previous  
   Exec=rhythmbox-client --previous  
   TargetEnvironment=Unity  

   [Next Shortcut Group]  
   Name=Next  
   Exec=rhythmbox-client --next  
   TargetEnvironment=Unity  

   [Stop Shortcut Group]  
   Name=Stop  
   Exec=rhythmbox-client --stop  
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. Save the file.

Comment: @Roland: Fixed.

Answer (score 17):

## Google Chrome Quicklist

[image: chrome quicklist]

1. Copy the Google Chrome launcher to your home directory, in Terminal paste the following:

   ```
   cp /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open this file for editing:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
   ```
3. Highlight and copy the text below, then paste it at the **bottom** of the file.

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;Incognito;

   [NewWindow Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Window
   Exec=google-chrome
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Incognito Shortcut Group]
   Name=New incognito window
   Exec=google-chrome --incognito
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

[Source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jamesgifford/unity-quicklist-examples/trunk/files)

Comment: This is now default in the stable build.

Answer (score 17):

## Thunderbird Quicklist

[image: Thunderbird Lanuncher]

1. Copy the launcher file to your home directory:

   `cp /usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop`
2. Open the file with Text Editor

   `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop`
3. Add the text at the bottom of the file and save it.

   `X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Compose;AddressBook;ProfileManager;`

   ```
   [Compose Shortcut Group]
   Name=Compose
   Exec=thunderbird -compose
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [AddressBook Shortcut Group]
   Name=Address Book
   Exec=thunderbird -addressbook
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [ProfileManager Shortcut Group]
   Name=Profile Manager
   Exec=thunderbird -ProfileManager
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

Answer (score 16):

## Mines Quicklist

Quickly launch new games of Mine from the launcher.

[image: mines quicklist]

1. Copy the Mines launcher to your home directory, in Terminal paste the following:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/gnomine.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open this file for editing:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gnomine.desktop
   ```
3. Highlight and copy the text below, then paste it at the **bottom** of the .desktop file.

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Small;Medium;Large;

   [Small Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Game (Small)
   Exec=gnomine -f 0
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Medium Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Game (Medium)
   Exec=gnomine -f 1
   TargetEnviroment=Unity

   [Large Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Game (Large)
   Exec=gnomine -f 2
   TargetEnviroment=Unity
   ```

[Source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jamesgifford/unity-quicklist-examples/trunk/view/head:/mines.desktop)

Answer (score 15):

## Déjà Dup Quicklist

[image: Déjà Dup Quicklist]

1. Copy *Déjà Dup* launcher file to your home directory with Terminal:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/deja-dup.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the file for editing in Text Editor:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/deja-dup.desktop
   ```
3. **Add** this text to the **bottom** of the file, then close and save:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=BackupNow;

   [BackupNow Shortcut Group]
   Name=Backup Now
   Exec=deja-dup --backup
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. Remove Déjà Dup Icon from Launcher (untick *Keep In Launcher*) then open the application from Dash, the new quicklist should appear and you can re-tick *Keep In Launcher*.

Comment: This is now in the default build.

Answer (score 14):

## Opera Quicklist

[image]

1. Copy your original .desktop file into your home directory for editing:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/opera-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open terminal and enter the following:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/opera-browser.desktop
   ```
3. At the bottom of the file, add the following lines, then save and close:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewTab;NewPrivateTab;NewWindow;Mail;

   [NewTab Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Tab
   Exec=opera -newtab
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [NewPrivateTab Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Private Tab
   Exec=opera -newprivatetab
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [NewWindow Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Window
   Exec=opera -newwindow
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Mail Shortcut Group]
   Name=Mail
   Exec=opera -mail
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. Add the icon to your launcher if it is not already and your quicklists should now be working.

**Tips**:

You can also make Mail open a new tab at a specific address if you want by replacing its Exec command to be (for example):

```
Exec=opera -newtab "http://www.gmail.com/"
```

Sources, [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34410/how-do-i-add-a-static-quicklist-for-opera-to-open-new-tabs-and-windows), [2](http://kyleabaker.com/2011/04/02/quicklists-for-opera-in-unity/), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34410/how-do-i-add-a-static-quicklist-for-opera-to-open-new-tabs-and-windows)

Comment: As of May 7, 2011: http://kyleabaker.com/2011/05/07/unity-opera/ Contains: download progress, open tabs count, show urgency, extensive quicklist.

Comment: See below for **Opera quick list (part 2) and more**.

Answer (score 14):

### Transmission Quicklist

[image]

1. Copy the global `transmission-gtk.desktop` file to your home directory:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/transmission-gtk.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Edit the file:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/transmission-gtk.desktop
   ```
3. Paste the following code to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Pause All;Start All;

   [Pause All Shortcut Group]
   Name=Pause All
   Exec=transmission-remote -tall --stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Start All Shortcut Group]
   Name=Start All
   Exec=transmission-remote -tall --start
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

You may also show number of downloading torrents and total progress indicator using script from https://github.com/kriomant/transmission-unity-launcher

Answer (score 14):

### Ubuntu One Quicklist

Connect to the server, disconnect from the server and stop the Ubuntu One syncdaemon quickly.

[image]

1. **Copy** the original Ubuntu One Control Panel icon to your home directory for editing:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```
2. **Open the file for editing** with gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk.desktop
   ```
3. **Highlight and copy** the text below, then **paste** it at the bottom of the .desktop file:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Connect;Disconnect;Quit

   [Connect Shortcut Group]
   Name=Connect
   Exec=u1sdtool --connect
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Disconnect Shortcut Group]
   Name=Disconnect
   Exec=u1sdtool --disconnect
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Quit Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop Ubuntu One
   Exec=u1sdtool --quit
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this - there are times when the syncing can get annoying (editing and building LaTeX documents, for example) and this gives an easy way to temporarily disable U1 without having to open up the program.

Answer (score 13):

## Firefox Quicklist Alternative

Puts a list of your favourite websites in the Firefox Quicklist.

[image: End Result]

1. Copy firefox.desktop to home.

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open for editing

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
   ```
3. Add to the bottom, edit the websites to your favorites

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=OMGUbuntu;WebUpd8;UbuntuForums;AskUbuntu;UbuntuLaunchpad;NewWindow
   [OMGUbuntu Shortcut Group]
   Name=OMG! Ubuntu
   Exec=firefox -new-window 'http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [WebUpd8 Shortcut Group]
   Name=WebUpd8
   Exec=firefox -new-window 'http://www.webupd8.org/'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [UbuntuForums Shortcut Group]
   Name=Ubuntu Forums
   Exec=firefox -new-window 'http://ubuntuforums.org'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [AskUbuntu Shortcut Group]
   Name=Ask Ubuntu
   Exec=firefox -new-window 'http://askubuntu.com/'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [UbuntuLaunchpad Shortcut Group]
   Name=Ubuntu Launchpad
   Exec=firefox -new-window 'https://launchpad.net/ubuntu'
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [NewWindow Shortcut Group]
   Name=Open a New Window
   Exec=firefox -new-window about:blank
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

Answer (score 13):

## Gnome-Terminal Quicklist (auto-update from ssh config)

Here is a small shell script that updates your Gnome-Terminal-Quicklist with all your server entries in your `~/.ssh/config` file. No manual manipulation is required. It reads your `~/.ssh/config` file and creates the menu items from it. It also adds the "Root Terminal" menu entry.

[image: Gnome terminal quicklist with ssh entries]

1. Copy the script listed below into an empty file and put it in your scripts-folder (we will assume that is `~/bin/` and the script name you choose is `unityterm.sh`).
2. Run the script once to add the entries:

   ```
   /bin/bash ~/bin/unityterm.sh
   ```
3. Optionally you may have cron run the script for you every once in a while. To add it to cron, type the follwing command into a shell:

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```

   An editor will open. There add a line like:

   ```
   @reboot /bin/bash/ $HOME/bin/unityterm.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
   ```

   If you don't do this step, you'll have to run the script by hand every time you change your `~/.ssh/config` if you want the quicklist updated.
4. Changes only take effect on your next login or after you Alt+F2ing

   ```
   unity --replace
   ```

   So do that. *Note: Don't run `unity --replace` in a terminal. If you close that terminal, it will kill unity with it.*
5. Enjoy and have a look at the [similar script for nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/43150#43150) that parses your nautilus bookmarks.

### Script:

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# indent-mode: spaces, tabsize: 4, encoding: utf8
#
# © 2011 con-f-use@gmx.net. Use under the MIT license:
#     http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
#
# CONTRIBUTORS: jacopoL <jacopo.jl@gmail.com>
#
# This script updates the unity quicklist menu for gnome-terminal to contain
#+the user's bookmarks. The updates will have efect after unity is restarted
#+(eigther after the next login or by invoking 'unity --replace').

# location of template, unity bar launchers and ssh config file
tertempl="/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop"
target="$HOME/.local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop"
bookmarks="$HOME/.ssh/config"

# backup if file allready exists
if [ -e "$target" ]; then
    echo "Creating backup of: $target."
    mv -n "$target" "$target.bak"
fi

# copy template
cp "$tertempl" "$target"
if ! grep -q 'OnlyShowIn=.*Unity' "$target"; then # add only if not already present
    sed -i "s/\(OnlyShowIn=.*\)/\1Unity;/" "$target"
fi

# add entries to template
if ! grep -q 'X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=' "$target"; then # add only if not already present
    echo -e "\nX-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=\n" >> "$target"
else
    echo >> "$target"
fi
bmcount=0        # number of current bookmark
while read bmline; do # walk lines in ssh config file
    # when a new host is found, write the data collected in previous loops
    test=$(echo "$bmline" | grep -oE 'Host[[:space:]]')
    if [ -n "$test" ]; then
        ishost=$(echo "$bmline" | sed -e 's/[ ^I]*Host[ ^I]\+\([-_\.A-Za-z0-9]\+\).*/\1/g')
    fi
    if [ -n "$ishost" ]; then
        if [ -n "$hostname" ]; then
            # write bookmark information
            cat - >> "$target" <<____________EOF
                [Scg$bmcount Shortcut Group]
                Name=SSH into $oldhost
                Exec=gnome-terminal -x ssh $sshuser$hostname
                TargetEnvironment=Unity

____________EOF
            # extend shortcut list with current bookmark, prepending a ; if needed
            sed -i "s/\(X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=\(.*;$\|$\)\)/\1Scg${bmcount};/
                    t
                    s/\(X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=.*\)/\1;Scg${bmcount};/" "$target"
            bmcount=$(($bmcount+1))
        fi
        hostname=""
        sshuser=""
        oldhost="$ishost"
        ishost=""
    fi
    # collect data: hostname
    test=$(echo "$bmline" | grep -oE 'HostName[[:space:]]')
    if [ -n "$test" ]; then
        hostname=$(echo "$bmline" | sed -e 's/[ ^I]*HostName[ ^I]\+\([-_\.A-Za-z0-9]\+\).*/\1/g')
    fi
    # collect data: ssh user
    test=$(echo "$bmline" | grep -oE 'User[[:space:]]')
    if [ -n "$test" ]; then
        sshuser=$(echo "$bmline" | sed -e 's/[ ^I]*User[ ^I]\+\([-_\.A-Za-z0-9]\+\).*/\1@/g')
    fi
done < "$bookmarks"
# write bookmark information of last bookmark
#+and add a root file manager entry
cat - >> "$target" <<EOF
    [Scg$bmcount Shortcut Group]
    Name=SSH into $oldhost
    Exec=gnome-terminal -x ssh $sshuser$hostname
    TargetEnvironment=Unity

    [RootTM Shortcut Group]
    Name=Root Terminal
    Exec=gksudo gnome-terminal
    TargetEnvironment=Unity
EOF
# extend shortcut list with last bookmark and root file manager
sed -i "s/\(X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=.*\)/\1Scg${bmcount};/" "$target"
sed -i "s/\(X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=.*\)/\1RootTM;/" "$target"

# Cleanup extra whitespaces
sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]\+//g' "$target"

exit 0
```

Answer (score 12):

## Extended Home Icon Quicklist

[image: Quick Lists]

1. Copy 'Home Folder' launcher file to your home directory with Terminal:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the file for editing in gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop
   ```
3. **Delete** the following line from the file:

   ```
   OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
   ```
4. **Add** this text to the **bottom** of the file, then close and save:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Amazon;Backgrounds;CD Covers;Documents;Downloads;Dropbox;DVD Projects;Google Earth;Listings;Music;Notes;Photographs;Podcasts;Public;Templates;Themes;Transmission;Videos

   [Amazon Shortcut Group]
   Name=Amazon
   Exec=nautilus Amazon
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Backgrounds Shortcut Group]
   Name=Backgrounds
   Exec=nautilus Backgrounds
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [CD Covers Shortcut Group]
   Name=CD Covers
   Exec=nautilus CDCovers
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Documents Shortcut Group]
   Name=Documents
   Exec=nautilus Documents
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Dropbox Shortcut Group]
   Name=Dropbox
   Exec=nautilus Dropbox
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Downloads Shortcut Group]
   Name=Downloads
   Exec=nautilus Downloads

   [DVD Projects Shortcut Group]
   Name=DVD Projects
   Exec=nautilus DVDProjects
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Google Earth Shortcut Group]
   Name=Google Earth
   Exec=nautilus GoogleEarth
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Listings Shortcut Group]
   Name=Listings
   Exec=nautilus Listings
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Notes Shortcut Group]
   Name=Notes
   Exec=nautilus Notes
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Photographs Shortcut Group]
   Name=Photographs
   Exec=nautilus Photographs
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Podcasts Shortcut Group]
   Name=Podcasts
   Exec=nautilus Podcasts
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Public Shortcut Group]
   Name=Public
   Exec=nautilus Public
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Templates Shortcut Group]
   Name=Templates
   Exec=nautilus Templates
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Themes Shortcut Group]
   Name=Themes
   Exec=nautilus Themes
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Transmission Shortcut Group]
   Name=Transmission
   Exec=nautilus Transmission
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Videos Shortcut Group]
   Name=Videos
   Exec=nautilus Videos
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
5. Log out and log in again to see the changes.

Comment: Please use the same formatting and layout as the other answers.

Comment: Wow, that's... overkill. Anything more than five or six options, and you spend as much time searching through the menu as you would just navigating to the folder.

Comment: Well that's a good comment to make, but it makes accessing a specific folder just that much quicker. I consider it just a way to get to my bookmarks. Give it a try, you may like it.

Comment: but its useless for others, because this script is especially written for YOUR Homefolder.

Comment: @Pablo YOU can tailor it to YOUR home folder.

Comment: I like it, scouser73. It now gives me an idea for something new. You get an upvote.

Answer (score 12):

### DeaDBeeF Quicklist

[image: DeaDBeeF Quicklist]

1. Copy launcher file to your home directory:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/deadbeef.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the file for editing in gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/deadbeef.desktop
   ```
3. Add this text to the bottom of the file, then close and save:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play;Pause;Stop;Next;Prev
   [Play Shortcut Group]
   Name=Play
   Exec=deadbeef --play
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Pause Shortcut Group]
   Name=Pause
   Exec=deadbeef --pause
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Stop Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop
   Exec=deadbeef --stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Next Shortcut Group]
   Name=Next
   Exec=deadbeef --next
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Prev Shortcut Group]
   Name=Prev
   Exec=deadbeef --prev
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. *Optional:* Change the drag & drop function of the launcher so it appends files to the playlist instead of clearing it:

   **Find** `Exec=deadbeef %F` and **Replace** with `Exec=deadbeef --queue %F`

---

There are a few other commands available in `deadbeef -h` but these are the only ones that seem useful in a quicklist.

Answer (score 12):

## Opera Launcher & Quicklist (Part 2)

- **Tab counter**

  The total number of tabs you have open appears on the Launcher icon and is updated in real time as you open and close tabs;
- **Urgency**

  When Opera is not in focus and a new tab is opened, the Opera icon in the Launcher now enters urgency mode and wiggles once;
- **Quicklist**

  With (at the moment) limited support for Opera’s built in Mail client (M2).

  [image: Quicklist]  [image: Urgency] [image: Tab count]

### Installation

1. Extract the script from this [zip](http://www.kyleabaker.com/downloads/opera/scripts/unity-opera/unity-opera.zip) into your home folder.
2. Open **Startup Applications** and add an entry using the above script as follows:

   *Command:* `python unity-opera.py`

   [image: startup]

[Source](http://kyleabaker.com/2011/05/07/unity-opera/)

Kudos go to Kyle Baker!

Answer (score 12):

**Custom Scripts Quicklist with GUI**

[image]

Create Quicklist launcher for your scripts. Embedded GUI with automatic and manual option for adding entries.
The automatic option can only add, with the manual you can modify the file directly.

**1. Create custom .desktop file for launcher**

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/my_scripts.desktop
```

**2. Paste the following code and edit following:(line 5 is the way to folder with your scripts, in this example, this is folder with the name `Scripts`, you need to change it for your location. You can change also the line 6 which is an icon. And at the end change `<username>` text to match your home folder username.**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Scripts Folder
Comment=Open your scripts folder
TryExec=nautilus
Exec=xdg-open /home/<username>/Scripts
Icon=ibus-engine
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=AddScript

[AddScript Shortcut Group]
Name=Add New Script
Exec=/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/scripts/addscript
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

**3. Create a 'scripts' folder (if not exist) in ~/.local/share/applications folder:**

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/applications/scripts
```

**4. Create the script file 'addscript' with gedit (this is the GUI for adding entries to your quicklist):**

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/scripts/addscript
```

**5. Add this text to the file,then save and close**

```
#!/bin/bash
menuitem=`zenity --list --title="My Scripts Launcher Manager" \
--width=300 --height=150 \
--text="Select action" \
--column="Pick" --column="Action" \
--radiolist TRUE Add-Script-Automatically FALSE Add/Edit/Delete-Manually`
case $menuitem in
Add-Script-Automatically )
hkey=$(zenity --entry --text "Set  name for your script" --entry-text "" --title "Set name")
if [ -z "$hkey" ]; then
zenity --error --title "Set  name for your script "   --text="The script name is empty. Exiting ..."
exit 0
fi
ay=$(sed -n '/X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts/p' /$HOME/.local/share/applications/my_scripts.desktop)
shortname2=$(echo "$hkey" | sed 's/\///g')
shortname=$(echo "$shortname2" | sed 's/ /_/g')

hkey3=$(zenity --entry --text "Set command for your script" --entry-text "" --title "Set command")
if [ -z "$hkey3" ]; then
zenity --error --title "Set command "   --text="The command is empty. Exiting ..."
exit 0
fi

sed -i "s/$ay/$ay;$shortname/g" /$HOME/.local/share/applications/my_scripts.desktop
echo "" >>  /$HOME/.local/share/applications/my_scripts.desktop
echo "[$shortname Shortcut Group]" >>  /$HOME/.local/share/applications/my_scripts.desktop
echo "Name=$hkey" >>  /$HOME/.local/share/applications/my_scripts.desktop
echo "Exec=$hkey3" >>  /$HOME/.local/share/applications/my_scripts.desktop
echo "TargetEnvironment=Unity" >> /$HOME/.local/share/applications/my_scripts.desktop


zenity --info --title "New entry added" --text "Changes only take effect on next login"
;;
Add/Edit/Delete-Manually)
zenity --text-info --filename=/$HOME/.local/share/applications/my_scripts.desktop > /tmp/my_scripts.desktop.edited  --title "Add/Edit/Delete Script"  --editable --width 850 --height 480
cp /tmp/my_scripts.desktop.edited /$HOME/.local/share/applications/my_scripts.desktop
rm /tmp/my_scripts.desktop.edited
zenity --info --title "New entry added" --text "Changes only take effect on next login"
;;
esac
```

**6. Make the file executable:**

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/scripts/addscript
```

**7.Drag & Drop the `my_scripts.desktop` file from `~/.local/share/applications` in nautilus to the Unity Launcher Bar**

**8. You can start adding entries to your quicklist with clicking on "`Add New Script`" menu item**

Answer (score 11):

## VirtualBox Quicklist

This adds a quicklist entry for your Virtualbox virtual machines. The following example uses 'Windows XP' so will require editing to match your own VM details.

1. Copy the file to your home directory

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop
   ```
2. Open the file with Text Editor

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop
   ```
3. Add the text at the bottom of the file and save it.

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=WindowsXP

   [WindowsXP Shortcut Group]
   Name=Start Windows XP
   Exec=/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox --comment "Windows XP" --startvm "Windows XP"
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. Drag & Drop the virtualbox.desktop file from ~/.local/share/applications in nautilus to the Unity Launcher Bar

Comment: This only works if you have a VM named "Windows XP". Fortunately, by editing the file yourself, you can add your own VMs.

Comment: A custom launcher could be created to list VMs such as the [Virtualbox Indicator](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators/38057#38057) currently does.

Answer (score 11):

## UMPlayer Quicklist

[image]

- Copy the original .desktop file to your home folder:

  `cp /usr/share/applications/umplayer.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`
- Open that desktop file for editing :

  `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/umplayer.desktop`
- Add the following at the bottom of the file.

  ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play;Pause;Stop;Fullscreen;

   [Play Shortcut Group]
   Name=Play
   Exec=umplayer -send-action play
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Pause Shortcut Group]
   Name=Pause
   Exec=umplayer -send-action pause
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Stop Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop
   Exec=umplayer -send-action stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Fullscreen Shortcut Group]
   Name=Fullscreen
   Exec=umplayer -send-action fullscreen
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
  ```
- Save it and navigate to `~/.local/share/applications/` and then drag it to the launcher .

Answer (score 10):

## Quicklist for Music Player Daemon (MPD) clients

[image: Screenshot]

Adds play/pause, previous, next and stop to the launcher of an MPD client (in this case GMPC, but this can easily be adapted for e.g. xfmpc, Sonata, Ario, Pygmy, pympd, Glurp, Gimmix, gbemol or whatever you fancy). The only requirement is that you install the package mpc (`sudo apt-get install mpc`).

1. Copy the global gmpc.desktop file to your home directory:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/gmpc.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Edit the file:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gmpc.desktop
   ```
3. Paste the following code to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play/Pause;Previous;Next;Stop

   [Play/Pause Shortcut Group]
   Name=Play/Pause
   Exec=mpc toggle
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Previous Shortcut Group]
   Name=Previous
   Exec=mpc prev
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Next Shortcut Group]
   Name=Next
   Exec=mpc next
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Stop Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop
   Exec=mpc stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

PS. For extra integration, install [mpd-sound-menu](https://launchpad.net/mpd-sound-menu).

Answer (score 8):

### Clementine Quicklist

[image]

Adds play, pause, stop, next, and back to the clementine launcher.

1. Copy the global clementine.desktop file to your home directory:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/clementine.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Edit the file:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/clementine.desktop
   ```
3. Paste the following code to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play;Pause;Stop;Previous;Next  

   [Play Shortcut Group]
   Name=Play
   Exec=clementine --play
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Pause Shortcut Group]
   Name=Pause
   Exec=clementine --pause
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Stop Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop
   Exec=clementine --stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Previous Shortcut Group]
   Name=Previous
   Exec=clementine --previous
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Next Shortcut Group]
   Name=Next
   Exec=clementine --next
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

Answer (score 7):

**gFTP Quicklist**

[image: h]

Access directly the bookmarked sites with gFtp. In Launcher is included the script for **Bookmarks List** generating

1. Copy the global gftp.desktop file to your home directory:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/gftp.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the file for editing with gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   ```
3. Paste the following code to the bottom of the file change only the `<username>` to yours:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=GenerateB;EditB

   [GenerateB Shortcut Group]
   Name=Create Bookmarks List
   Exec=/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/scripts/addbookmarks generateb
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [EditB Shortcut Group]
   Name=Edit gFTP Bookmarks
   Exec=/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/scripts/addbookmarks editb
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. Create a 'scripts' folder (if not exist) in ~/.local/share/applications folder:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.local/share/applications/scripts
   ```
5. Create the script file 'addbookmarks' with gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/scripts/addbookmarks
   ```
6. Add this text to the file

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   case $1 in
   generateb)
   echo "[Desktop Entry]" >  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Encoding=UTF-8" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Name=gFTP" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Comment=Download and upload files using multiple file transfer protocols" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "GenericName=gFTP" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Exec=gftp %u" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Terminal=false" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "X-MultipleArgs=false" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Type=Application" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Icon=gftp.png" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Categories=Application;Network;" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gftp" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general" >>  /$HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.0.19" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gftp" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   awk 'NR>1{print $1}' RS=[ FS=] $HOME/.gftp/bookmarks > /tmp/gftpbookmarks
   N=0
   while read LINE ; do
       N=$((N+1))
   ay=$(sed -n '/X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts/p' $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop)
   shortname=$(echo "FtpSite$N")


   sed -i "s/$ay/$ay$shortname;/g" $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "[$shortname Shortcut Group]" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Name=$LINE" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Exec=gftp "bookmark://$LINE"" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "TargetEnvironment=Unity" >> $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop

   done < /tmp/gftpbookmarks
   rm /tmp/gftpbookmarks

   ay2=$(sed -n '/X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts/p' $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop)
   ay3="GenerateB;EditB"
   sed -i "s/$ay2/$ay2$ay3/g" $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "[GenerateB Shortcut Group]" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Name=Create Bookmarks List" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Exec=$HOME/.local/share/applications/scripts/addbookmarks generateb" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "TargetEnvironment=Unity" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "[EditB Shortcut Group]" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Name=Edit gFTP Bookmarks" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "Exec=$HOME/.local/share/applications/scripts/addbookmarks editb" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop
   echo "TargetEnvironment=Unity" >>  $HOME/.local/share/applications/gftp.desktop

   zenity --question --text="Your Bookmarks List has been generated. A restart of Unity Is Required to take effect! Would you like to perform this  now?"
   qq=$?
   if [ "$qq" -eq "0" ] ; then 
       unity --replace &
   else
       exit 1
   fi
   ;;

   editb)
   zenity --text-info --filename=$HOME/.gftp/bookmarks > /tmp/gftpbookmarks  --title "Modify gFTP Bookmarks"  --editable --width 850 --height 480
   cp /tmp/gftpbookmarks $HOME/.gftp/bookmarks
   rm /tmp/gftpbookmarks
   ;;

   esac
   ```
7. Make the file executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/scripts/addbookmarks
   ```
8. Drag & Drop the gftp.desktop file from ~/.local/share/applications in nautilus to the Unity Launcher Bar
9. FIRST RUN !!

   Click on the "**Edit gFTP Bookmarks**" menu item and edit your gftp bookmarks file. By default file contains a lot of ftp sites which are not used. Remove unused bookmarks and close the file. Next, click on the "**Create Bookmark List**" and your list is generated.

   List editing is with the same way, at first edit the bookmarks list, next generate the new one.

Answer (score 6):

**Exaile Unity quicklist**

Adds play/pause/stop/previous/next entries to Exaile.

Preview:

[image]

1. Copy exaile.desktop to home folder's local share

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/exaile.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Edit it

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/exaile.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following to the end of the .desktop file

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play;Pause;Stop;Previous;Next;

   [Play Shortcut Group]
   Name=Play
   Exec=exaile --play
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Pause Shortcut Group]
   Name=Pause
   Exec=exaile --play-pause
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Stop Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop
   Exec=exaile --stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Previous Shortcut Group]
   Name=Previous
   Exec=exaile --previous
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Next Shortcut Group]
   Name=Next
   Exec=exaile --next
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

Answer (score 6):

## Quod Libet Quicklist

(new user not allowed to post image :( )

1. Copy quodlibet.desktop to home folder's local share

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/quodlibet.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Edit it

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/quodlibet.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following to the end of the .desktop file

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play;Pause;Previous;Next;Shuffle;InOrder;Focus;Hide;

   [Play Shortcut Group]
   Name=Play
   Exec=quodlibet --play
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Pause Shortcut Group]
   Name=Pause
   Exec=quodlibet --pause
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Previous Shortcut Group]
   Name=Previous
   Exec=quodlibet --previous
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Next Shortcut Group]
   Name=Next
   Exec=quodlibet --next
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Shuffle Shortcut Group]
   Name=Shuffle
   Exec=quodlibet --order=shuffle
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [InOrder Shortcut Group]
   Name=InOrder
   Exec=quodlibet --order=inorder
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Focus Shortcut Group]
   Name=Focus
   Exec=quodlibet --focus
   TargetEnviroment=Unity

   [Hide Shortcut Group]
   Name=Hide
   Exec=quodlibet --hide-window
   TargetEnviroment=Unity
   ```

Answer (score 6):

### Quicklist for Sonata (MPD client)

[image: Sonata Quicklists]

Main point here is to show simple integration with [last.fm](http://www.last.fm/) through [pylast](http://code.google.com/p/pylast/) and [MPC](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Client:Mpc) for any MPD client, without using additional modules

*Create custom sonata.desktop file in home folder:*

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/sonata.desktop
```

*Paste contents:*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sonata
Comment=Elegant GTK+ music client for the Music Player Daemon
Exec=sonata
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=sonata.svg
Categories=GNOME;Application;AudioVideo;
StartupNotify=true
Encoding=UTF-8

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play-Pause;Stop;Previous;Next;Love;Ban;Queue;Add-playing-album;Spectrogram;Audacity

[Play-Pause Shortcut Group]
Name=[ ▯▷ ]  Play/Pause
Exec=sonata pp
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Stop Shortcut Group]
Name=[  ◻  ]  Stop
Exec=sonata stop
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Previous Shortcut Group]
Name=[ ▯◁ ]  Previous
Exec=sonata prev
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Next Shortcut Group]
Name=[ ▷▯ ]  Next
Exec=sonata next
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Love Shortcut Group]
Name=(  ❤  )  Love track
Exec=bash /home/zetah/scripts/mpd-script.sh love
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Ban Shortcut Group]
Name=(  ✖  )  Ban track
Exec=bash /home/zetah/scripts/mpd-script.sh ban
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Queue Shortcut Group]
Name=(  ✚  )  Queue similar
Exec=bash /home/zetah/scripts/mpd-script.sh similar
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Add-playing-album Shortcut Group]
Name=Add Current Album
Exec=bash /home/zetah/scripts/mpd-script.sh add-album
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Spectrogram Shortcut Group]
Name=Spectrogram
Exec=bash /home/zetah/scripts/mpd-script.sh wavespec
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Audacity Shortcut Group]
Name=Open with Audacity
Exec=bash /home/zetah/scripts/mpd-script.sh audacity
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

For example "Queue similar" adds similar tracks to currently playing according last.fm match query.

Referenced scripts:
[mpd-script.sh](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/472294/)
[pylast-track.py](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/472295/)

Answer (score 5):

## Wine programs Quicklist

[image]

Example with menu items for Dreamweaver and Photoshop.

**1. Create custom .desktop file for launcher**

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-wine.desktop
```

**2. Paste the following code and replace the `<username>` text to match your home folder username. You need also define variable for each program (variable is after the wine_shortcuts) and then save & close:**

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=Browse C: Drive
Comment=Open your personal folder
TryExec=nautilus
Exec=xdg-open .wine/dosdevices/c:
Icon=wine
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Dreamweaver;Photoshop;ConfigureWine;Winetricks
[Dreamweaver Shortcut Group]
Name=Macromedia Dreaweaver
Exec=/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/scripts/wine_shortcuts dreamweaver
TargetEnvironment=Unity


[Photoshop Shortcut Group]
Name=Adobe Photoshop
Exec=/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/scripts/wine_shortcuts photoshop
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[ConfigureWine Shortcut Group]
Name=Configure Wine
Exec=winecfg
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Winetricks Shortcut Group]
Name=Winetricks
Exec=winetricks
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

**3. Create a 'scripts' folder (if it does not exist already) in `~/.local/share/applications` folder:**

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/applications/scripts
```

**4. Create the script file `wine_shortcuts` with gedit:**

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/scripts/wine_shortcuts
```

**5. Add this text to the file, setup variables used in step 2, open alacarte and get current command prefix for you program (here is posted only example), replace the `<command for dreamweaver/photoshop goes here>` then save and close:**

```
    #!/bin/bash

    case $1 in
    dreamweaver)
    <command for dreamweaver goes here>
    ;;
    photoshop)
    <command for photoshop goes here>
    ;;
    esac
```

**6. Make the file executable:**

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/scripts/wine_shortcuts
```

**7.Drag & drop the nautilus-wine.desktop file from ~/.local/share/applications in nautilus to the Unity Launcher Bar**

**Notice:**
variable in 2.) must be the same in 4.)

Example for dreamweaver:

2.)

```
Exec=/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/scripts/wine_shortcuts dreamweaver
```

4.)

```
 #!/bin/bash

 case $1 in
 dreamweaver)
```

Answer (score 4):

### Remmina Quicklist

There is a project in Google Code with a script for automatically creating the quicklist for Remmina, listing saved connections.

Here is the homepage of the project, with installation instructions:
http://code.google.com/p/remmina-unity-launcher/

I have modified the original script, to solve two issues (connection name not correctly found, sort connections by name), here is the script to launch.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Script to integrate Remmina into Unity Launch bar.
# Creator: Daniel Scholtus
# Version: 2
# Date:    March 23, 2011

if [ -e ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop ]
then
    echo "Deleting old Launcher"
    rm ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
fi

echo "Creating Base Launcher"
cp /usr/share/applications/remmina.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop

echo "Adding shortcuts items declaration"
echo "" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop

AYATANA="X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts="

mkdir /tmp/remmina-unity

FILES=("`ls ~/.remmina/*.remmina`")
for f in ${FILES}
do
    NAME=`cat $f | grep -G -m 1 ^name= | cut -d= -f2`
    FILE=`basename $f .remmina`
    echo $FILE > "/tmp/remmina-unity/$NAME"
done

FILESTEMP=("`ls /tmp/remmina-unity/*`")
for f in ${FILESTEMP}
do
    FILE=`cat "$f"`
    AYATANA=$AYATANA$FILE";"
done

rm /tmp/remmina-unity/ -R

AYATANA=$AYATANA"Settings;Update;Restart"

echo $AYATANA >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop

echo "Adding shortcuts items descriptions"
echo "" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop

echo " - Settings"
echo "[Settings Shortcut Group]" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "Name=Settings" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "Exec=remmina" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "TargetEnvironment=Unity" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop

echo " - Update"
echo "[Update Shortcut Group]" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "Name=Update List (needs to re-lock to the panel)" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "Exec=bash ~/.local/bin/remmina-unity.sh" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "TargetEnvironment=Unity" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop

echo " - Restart"
echo "" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "[Restart Shortcut Group]" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "Name=Update List and restart Unity" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "Exec=bash ~/.local/bin/remmina-unity.sh & setsid unity --replace" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
echo "TargetEnvironment=Unity" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop

for f in ${FILES}
do
    NAME=`cat $f | grep -G -m 1 ^name= | cut -d= -f2`

    echo " - "$NAME
    echo "" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
    echo "[`basename $f .remmina` Shortcut Group]" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
    echo "Name=$NAME" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
    echo "Exec=remmina -c $f" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
    echo "TargetEnvironment=Unity" >> ~/.local/share/applications/remmina.desktop
done
```

Answer (score 3):

## Gwibber

There is a quick list by default for [**Gwibber**](http://gwibber.com/) (a microblogging client that brings the most popular social networking web services to your desktop).

[image: Gwibber quick-list]
this program comes with Ubuntu by default

---

Tip: This programs must be opened(or found in startup menu) to see it's quick-list

Comment: Please split these into separate answers.

Comment: @Roland Taylor done and sorry for late

Answer (score 2):

## Shutter:

There is a quick list by default for [**shutter**](http://shutter-project.org/) (a program to take screen-shots and edit them) when you install it Ubuntu unity.

[image: shutter quick-list]

Download shutter(ppa & .dep) : [here](http://shutter-project.org/downloads/)

---

Tip: This programs must be opened(or found in startup menu) to see it's quick-list

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy 'System Settings' launcher file to your home directory:

   `cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop ~/.local/share/applications`
2. Open the file for editing in gedit:

   `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop`
3. **Add** this text to the **bottom** of the file, then close and save:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=GnomeTweak;DiskUtility
   [GnomeTweak Shortcut Group]
   Name=Advanced Settings
   Exec=gnome-tweak-tool
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   [DiskUtility Shortcut Group]
   Name=Disk Utility
   Exec=palimpsest
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. Save the launcher and put it on the Unity panel in place of the original. Note that to have the Advanced Settings quicklist shortcut to work, the package "gnome-tweak-tool" must be installed (available in the repositories).

Comment: What exactly does this quicklist do? It sounds to me that this is equivalent to unpinning System Settings from the launcher and pinning Advanced Settings there instead, which could be easily accomplished with some drag-and-drop.

Comment: No, it allows me to quickly access a bunch of user settings from a single unity launcher instead of hunting them down each time in dash. I still want to keep System Settings on the dash and for that launcher to be the primary shortcut, but I want quicklist shortcut access to Advanced Settings and Disk Utility, even though I use them less often.

Answer (score 0):

## Audacious Quicklist

[image: Audacious Quicklist]

Quicklist for Audacious that allows controlling playback (redundant if using Audacious 3.2+, because you can control it from the Sound Menu), showing and hiding the main window (you can also unhide it by selecting Audacious from the Sound Menu), adding files to the current playlist and jumping to another song in the playlist.

1. Copy the original launcher file to your home folder:

   ```
    mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
    cp /usr/share/applications/audacious2.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```
2. Open that file for editing:

   ```
    gedit ~/.local/share/applications/audacious2.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following at the **bottom** of the file, then close and save.

   ```
    X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play;Pause;Stop;Rew;Fwd;Hide;Show;AddFiles;Jump

    [Play Shortcut Group]
    Name=Play
    Exec=audacious -p
    TargetEnvironment=Unity

    [Pause Shortcut Group]
    Name=Pause
    Exec=audacious -u
    TargetEnvironment=Unity

    [Stop Shortcut Group]
    Name=Stop
    Exec=audacious -s
    TargetEnvironment=Unity

    [Rew Shortcut Group]
    Name=Previous
    Exec=audacious -r
    TargetEnvironment=Unity

    [Fwd Shortcut Group]
    Name=Next
    Exec=audacious -f
    TargetEnvironment=Unity

    [Hide Shortcut Group]
    Name=Hide
    Exec=audtool mainwin-show off
    TargetEnvironment=Unity

    [Show Shortcut Group]
    Name=Show
    Exec=audtool mainwin-show on
    TargetEnvironment=Unity

    [AddFiles Shortcut Group]
    Name=Add files
    Exec=audtool filebrowser-show
    TargetEnvironment=Unity

    [Jump Shortcut Group]
    Name=Jump to Song
    Exec=audacious -j
    TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. Log out and log in again to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

## Audacious Headless mode Quicklist

[image: Audacious Headless mode Quicklist]

Quicklist for Audacious that allows starting the player in headless mode and shutting it down.

While running in headless mode Audacious can be controlled from the Sound Menu (Audacious 3.2+ only), with the multimedia keys (or other keybindings), from the command line with the `audacious` and the `audtool` commands and so on.

1. Copy the original launcher file to your home folder:

   ```
    mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
    cp /usr/share/applications/audacious2.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```
2. Open that file for editing:

   ```
    gedit ~/.local/share/applications/audacious2.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following at the **bottom** of the file, then close and save.

   ```
    X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Headless;Shutdown

    [Headless Shortcut Group]
    Name=Start in headless mode
    Exec=audacious -h
    TargetEnvironment=Unity

    [Shutdown Shortcut Group]
    Name=Shutdown
    Exec=audtool shutdown
    TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. Log out and log in again to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

### Nginx Quicklist

[image: Nginx Quicklist]

1. Install [nginx-init-ubuntu](https://github.com/hulihanapplications/nginx-init-debian).
2. Add create a new file `.local/share/applications/` named `nginx.desktop` and paste this inside:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Nginx
   Comment=Nginx Webserver
   Exec=sudo service nginx start
   Icon=/usr/share/icons/nginx.png
   Type=Application
   Categories=Web;Servers;
   StartupNotify=true
   Terminal=true
   #OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
   X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nginx
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Start;Stop;Restart;

   [Start Shortcut Group]
   Name=Start Nginx
   Exec=sudo service nginx start
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Stop Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop Nginx
   Exec=sudo service nginx stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Restart Shortcut Group]
   Name=Restart Nginx
   Exec=sudo service nginx restart
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
3. Using your file manager (such as nautilus), drag `.local/share/applications/nginx.desktop` to the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

## Wallch:

There is a quick list by default for [**Wallch**](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/08/wallch-wallpaper-changer-adds-unity-features/) (a program to change wallpaper automatically) when you install it Ubuntu unity.

[image: wallch quick-list]

Download wallch(ppa & .dep) : [here](https://launchpad.net/~wallch/+archive/wallch-gnome2)

---

Tip: This programs must be opened(or found in startup menu) to see it's quick-list