# List of Quicklists available for Applications

Tags: unity, launcher, quicklists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the custom launchers and quicklists created for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-are-the-custom-launchers-and-quicklists-created-for-unity)

Quicklists are the right-click menu a for applications on the Unity Launcher and it would be nice to have a list of the best quicklists that have been created.