# Quicklist for Google Chrome (for bookmarks, new windows, etc) not working properly

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome, quicklists

I tried to make a quicklist for Google Chrome by editing the .desktop file in /opt/google/chrome but there is a small problem

If i already have an instance of google chrome running and then i use the quicklist's shorcuts, the new google chrome opens in the same icon as the first one, adding the triangle to the left (just as it is supposed to)
If, though, i don't have an instance of chrome already running and i use one of the shorcuts i get the new window in its own icon on the launcher - making the launcher have two google chrome icons : one with the quicklist enabled and one without it.

the code i used for the quicklist is :

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;Incognito;GoogleReader;  "Some more shorcuts here..."
Name[en_US]=Google Chrome
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
TargetEnvironment=Unity
[Incognito Shortcut Group]
Name=New incognito window
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --incognito
TargetEnvironment=Unity
[GoogleReader Shortcut Group]
Name=Google Reader
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome  %U http://www.google.com/reader/view/?hl=en#overview-page
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

and some more exactly like the google reader's shortcut group for the other shorcuts

Can someone help me with getting a working quicklist on chrome? 
I'm pretty sure others would like to use it too.

Comment: There's a bug with window matching with chrome right now so I have a feeling this is a bug; the chrome guys are aware and they've fixed it in the upstream chromium; but the unity team hasn't had a chance to look at yet, hoping to see a fix next week. Not entirely sure you're running into this bug so I'm going with "this is kind of weird and wonky right this moment" is the best answer I can come up with.

Comment: Which is probably why the (almost) same code seems to work with chromium, now that i have tried it. Makes sense then - i would probably jump over to chromium sooner or later anyway :D

Comment: It works in chromium because the chromium maintainer is backporting those fixes to the archive on a near-realtime basis. (he's awesome) They eventually make it to Chrome itself, just a bit slower. Post your solution as an answer so we can vote on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome seems to have a bug that causes this kind of behavior - one that is fixed in Chromium (at least on the daily version - 13.0.750.0 (83280) - that i tested) . 
The fix will , eventually, come to Chrome as well.

(when an update bring the fixed Chrome, i will post here a comment here - unless i have moved away to Chromium permanently)

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at the [List of custom Launchers & Quicklists for Unity: Google Chrome Quicklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/37764#37764) and there are some other quicklists you might like in there. For instance the [Google Services Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/35489#35489) and [Google Docs Quicklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/39132#39132).

Comment: -1 Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: So I should copy the entry from over there to here? Because the first link describes how to make the before mentioned functionality. But maybe I've misread the question.

Comment: You misread the question. It was a question about how Chrome operates, not how the Quicklist works/worked. :)

Comment: As you could see in the quicklists on that page, it might be due to the wrong exec-command. It just uses "Exec=google-chrome" instead of "Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome" for instance. As that quicklist is already known and (I haven't tested) working, I referred to that.

Comment: Possibly. I *have* been known to be wrong. Can you test that theory?