# Home Icon Quicklist can not be added to Unity dock

Tags: 11.04, unity, quicklists

I'm attempting to use the 'home icon quicklist' from [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/which-custom-unity-launchers-and-quicklists-do-you-use)

I've checked perms and the like, but I'm no expert on quicklist syntax so I figured I'd ask here since others may be having this problem if they've done an inline upgrade from Lucid or Karmic.

After logging back in, the icon disappears completely as if there's some type of syntax error.

I'm pretty sure the OnlyShowIn line might be affecting it - is this the case and which lines can I safely nuke from the "Gnome" list before the desktop shortcuts?  Is there a specific log file I can tail to take a look at why this might be failing?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Home Folder
Comment=Open your personal folder
TryExec=nautilus
Exec=nautilus --no-desktop
Icon=user-home
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Videos;Documents;Music;Pictures;Downloads
[Videos Shortcut Group]
Name=Videos
Exec=nautilus Videos
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Documents Shortcut Group]
Name=Documents
Exec=nautilus Documents
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Music Shortcut Group]
Name=Music
Exec=nautilus Music
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Pictures Shortcut Group]
Name=Pictures
Exec=nautilus Pictures
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Downloads Shortcut Group]
Name=Downloads
Exec=nautilus Downloads
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing this line and readding to the dock seems to have fixed the problem:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
```

You can also edit this line as follows:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

Comment: The single line OnlyShowIn=GNOME; should be the only one needing removed, the others although not required are useful.

Comment: That seems to be true.  Alternatively you can also add "Unity;" to the end of the OnlyShowIn line - it acts as a semicolon-delimited list.

Comment: Funnily enough I was reading the desktop entry specs and found that.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to reflect this change in resolution.