# Places menu in Unity

Tags: unity, places

Is there a places menu in Unity, similar to the one in the old gnome interface? I really liked having such quick access to remote shares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit]Apparently the places menu still exists, but they've buried it pretty well!

Since I didn't want to have to kick back to the desktop to access my places menu (I use my external shares pretty often), I added a Home Icon quicklist as outlined in [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/which-custom-unity-launchers-and-quicklists-do-you-use) to create, but added entries to my normal remote shares like so:

```
[Passport Shortcut Group]
Name=MyPassport External
Exec=nautilus smb://readyshare/mypassport/
```

Answer (score 8):

There is!

Minimise all your windows so only the Desktop is showing. (For a fast way of doing this press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Now move your mouse to the panel at the top of the screen, and click on places.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: wow, that's well concealed! :P

Comment: I have to agree, that's a terrible setup.  I should also add, it's not working for me. :/

Comment: I don't like the design at all... but hey. @Omega when you say it's not working, is it not showing up? Or just clicking on it does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that you can just click on the desktop, without minimising using Super+D, and when out move over the top panel Places is shown in the menu. This is quite quick and saves having to restore all your windows afterwards.

:¬}

Answer (score 1):

**Update Feb/24/2017:** The indicator now has option to pin links and open in default web browser (the one that is symlinked to `x-www-browser`).

#### Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer

Newer versions of Ubuntu do not have Places menu in the panel, however, there exists a set of indicators that can do the job. I've written Files Indicator, which originally was intended to display recent files only but now also incorporates Places menu. It displays user's standard folders as well as allows bookmarking/pinning your own directories.

[image]

The indicator is available from my personal PPA as well as [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/files-indicator). Use the following steps to obtain it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:1047481448-2/sergkolo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install files-indicator
```

Comment: Alternatively, one can use [Jacob Vlijm's indicator](http://askubuntu.com/a/851148/125220) - open-source choice and all that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the "files and folders" icon in the launcher. The content of that list though is not the same as your bookmarked folders in nautilus.

I've gotten used to just opening the "home" icon in the launcher to get the file manager and from there you'll see the bookmarks on the left side.

Comment: That's way too many steps to be considered even partially as convenient as how it used to be.

Comment: really? still two clicks in both scenarios.