# Is there a "Places" menu for Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: unity, indicator, menu, panel, places

I'd like to know if it's possible to put a "Places" tab in the upper menu of Ubuntu, such as CentOS, Debian, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Easily, but what should it exactly show?

Comment: main folders (home, downloads, document, etc) and the ones with bookmarks such as debian and centos

Comment: I see, will write one today or tomorrow if no one else did before I do :), or maybe one exists already (you mean an indicator, right?)

Comment: search "Places menu Debian" in Google Images and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Nope, that was a classic menu. All I found was outdated stuff with an inch of dust on it. I can fairly quickly write a basic one (and will). I would like to merge it with this one though: http://askubuntu.com/questions/803869/is-there-an-indicator-to-quickly-access-recently-used-files/804533#804533, which would make it an interesting project. The first shot today or tomorrow will therefore not be the final one. Nice question.

Comment: someone told me this can be done just using gnome instead of unity

Comment: i'll try and tell you when done, there's an oficcial image of ubuntu gnome 16.04 for the laziest ones haha but i dont see anything about places like debian

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried several existing ones, but could not find a *working* **Places** indicator. The ones I found were outdated, ppa's were no longer maintained.

#### Modular Places menu

So, below a freshly written one: **Places & Files indicator for Ubuntu**.

[image] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0HK8.png)

The ppa version is a *modular* one; you can choose what to show in the menu:

[[image]]

In the full version:

[image]

...or the smallest, only showing recently used:

[image]

#### Installing from ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/placesfiles
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install placesfiles
```

#### A simplified version to show a places menu, bookmarks and recently used files

*Description & (initial) code*

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3, GObject
import time
from threading import Thread
import os
import subprocess

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):

        currpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        self.home = os.environ["HOME"]
        self.bmark_file = os.path.join(self.home, ".config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks")
        self.def_file = os.path.join(self.home, ".config/user-dirs.dirs")
        self.recdata = os.path.join(self.home, ".local/share/recently-used.xbel")
        self.n = 10
        self.app = 'places'
        iconpath = os.path.join(currpath, "dir_icon.png")
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
        self.indicator.set_label("Places", self.app)
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())
        # the thread:
        self.update = Thread(target=self.check_recent)
        self.update.setDaemon(True)
        self.update.start()

    def create_menu(self):
        # creates the (initial) menu
        self.menu = Gtk.Menu()
        # separator
        initial = Gtk.MenuItem("Fetching list...")
        menu_sep = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        self.menu.append(initial)
        self.menu.append(menu_sep)
        # item_quit.show() 
        self.menu.show_all()
        return self.menu

    def open_directory(self, *args):
        index = self.menu.get_children().index(self.menu.get_active())
        selection = self.menu_items2[index-2]
        self.execute(["xdg-open", selection])

    def open_file(self, *args):
        index = self.submenu.get_children().index(self.submenu.get_active())
        selection = self.submenu2[index] 
        self.execute(["xdg-open", selection])

    def go_special(self, button, target):
        self.execute(["xdg-open", target])

    def connect(self, button):
        self.execute("nautilus-connect-server")

    def set_new(self):
        # update the list, appearing in the menu
        for i in self.menu.get_children():
            self.menu.remove(i)
        home_mention = Gtk.MenuItem("⌂ Home")
        home_mention.connect("activate", self.go_special, self.home)
        self.menu.append(home_mention)
        # separator
        menu_sep1 = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        self.menu.append(menu_sep1)
        for app in self.menu_items2:
            sub = Gtk.MenuItem("⏍ "+app.split("/")[-1])
            self.menu.append(sub)
            sub.connect('activate', self.open_directory)
        # separator
        menu_sep2 = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        self.menu.append(menu_sep2)
        # network
        network = "network:///"
        network_mention = Gtk.MenuItem("⇄ Network")
        network_mention.connect("activate", self.go_special, network)
        self.menu.append(network_mention)
        connect_mention = Gtk.MenuItem("⮁ Connect to server")
        connect_mention.connect("activate", self.connect)
        self.menu.append(connect_mention)
        # separator
        menu_sep3 = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        self.menu.append(menu_sep3)
        # computer
        computer = "computer:///"
        computer_mention = Gtk.MenuItem("⛁ Computer")
        computer_mention.connect("activate", self.go_special, computer)
        self.menu.append(computer_mention)
        recent_mention = Gtk.MenuItem("⁕ Recent files")
        self.menu.append(recent_mention)

        self.submenu = Gtk.Menu()
        for f in self.submenu2:
            recent = Gtk.MenuItem(f)
            recent.connect("activate", self.open_file)
            self.submenu.append(recent)
        recent_mention.set_submenu(self.submenu)
        # separator
        menu_sep6 = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        self.menu.append(menu_sep6)
        # quit
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        self.menu.append(item_quit)
        self.menu.show_all()

    def run_about(self, *args):
        self.execute("/opt/upfront/code/runabout")

    def check_recent(self):
        self.menu_items1 = []; self.submenu1 = []
        while True:
            time.sleep(4)
            self.menu_items2 = self.get_bookmarks()
            self.submenu2 = self.get_files()

            if any([self.menu_items2 != self.menu_items1,
                self.submenu2 != self.submenu1]):
                GObject.idle_add(
                    self.set_new, 
                    priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                    )
            self.menu_items1 = self.menu_items2
            self.submenu1 = self.submenu2

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def get_bookmarks(self):
        loc_bookmarks = [
            l.replace("file://", "") for l in open(self.bmark_file).read().splitlines()\
            if l.startswith("file://")
            ]
        netw_bookmarks = [
            l for l in open(self.bmark_file).read().splitlines()\
            if l.startswith("smb://")
            ]
        defaults = [
            os.path.join(self.home, l.replace('"', "").split("$HOME/")[-1]) for l in \
            open(self.def_file).read().splitlines() if all\
            (["$HOME/" in l, l.startswith("XDG")])
            ]
        return [self.replace_sc(m.split(" ")[0]).rstrip("/") for m in list(
            set(loc_bookmarks+defaults+netw_bookmarks))]

    def replace_sc(self, path):
        for c in [("%23", "#"), ("%5D", "]"), ("%5E", "^"),
                  ("file://", ""), ("%20", " ")]:
            path = path.replace(c[0], c[1])
        return path

    def execute(self, command):
        subprocess.Popen(command)

    def get_files(self):
        # create the list of recently used files
        used = [l for l in open(self.recdata) if all([
                    '<bookmark href="file://' in l, not "/tmp" in l, "." in l])]
        relevant = [l.split('="') for l in set(used)]
        relevant = [[it[1][7:-7], it[-2][:-10]] for it in relevant]
        relevant.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
        return [item[0].replace("%20", " ") for item in relevant[::-1][:self.n]]


Indicator()
GObject.threads_init()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

#### How to use (if not installed from ppa)

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `places_indicator.py`
2. Save the icon (right-click > save as) ***exactly*** named:

   ```
   dir_icon.png
   ```

   [image]

   ..in ***one and the same directory*** as the script.
3. Test- run the script by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/places_indicator.py
   ```
4. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python3 /path/to/places_indicator.py
   ```

#### About the indicator

The indicator shows:

1. The home directory
2. All directories (local bookmarks and smb) in

   - `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`
   - `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`
3. Network
4. Connect to network
5. Computer
6. Recently used files (lats 10 as it is, could be easily changed)

***Changing/added/removed bookmarks are updated dynamically***

Comment: pretty good, I've tried this on Unity and works thanks! But I decided to use Gnome though bec it looks more beautiful but I'll use this one for the recent filess feature too! thanks

Comment: @UlisesCT Ah, thanks for trying on Unity, despite the fact that you switched!

Comment: yeah! the problem is I come from Windows for desktop PC, and never used graphical stuff on Linux, just terminal on CentOS for servers and such, and when I installed ubuntu from ubuntu.es I thought its GUI was just that one and didn't know there's Gnome and Unity which you can choose (I missed the Places tab bec it was on CentOS which I tried to give a try as desktop but it kinda sucks). Good to keep on learning

Comment: Wow, that commitment - writing a new program to fulfil this need! Very impressed, well done @JacobVlijm! Why is it version 0.5.1-1 if you've only just written it though?

Comment: @Ads20000 Thanks! A few improvements; (re) moved or renamed files are now marked, a notification is shown if you (try) to open them, different recent-icon, now also works on 14.04, minor optimization of the code (filtering out special characters in filenames) etc.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Your work made it into an [OMG! Ubuntu! article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/places-indicator-applet-ubuntu-unity-desktop?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+d0od+%28OMG%21+Ubuntu%21%29)! Nice!

Comment: @Ads20000 Yeah! Nice, very nice :)

Answer (score 8):

**Update Feb/24/2017**: the indicator now has option for pinning web links

#### Introduction

NOTE: The previous version of this answer can be found under the edit history, althought it is no longer relevant.

The indicator presented below has been intended for a different question, but since opportunity presented itself, I've decided to release it here. The Files Indicator is simple indicator for accessing user's files and folders. It allows checking recently used files, bookmarking files and directories. In particular, the Places menu is specifically relevant to this question.

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the indicator also supports locales other than English, so if your system uses something other than English, it will work.

**Update**: indicator now also supports launching .desktop files that have been pinned. For instance if you have firefox.desktop pinned, it will launch firefox. Thus, the indicator can be used as quick launcher for programs. The feature is on the way into PPA at the time of writing (Nov 19, 7:53 pm GMT, should take about 24 hours to process), but is already on github as well as here, in updated source code.

[image]

#### Obtaining the indicator

The indicator is available from my personal PPA as well as [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/files-indicator). Use the following steps to obtain it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:1047481448-2/sergkolo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install files-indicator
```

#### Source code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com
# Date: November 19 , 2016
# Purpose: appindicator for accessing files and folders
# Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
#
#
# Licensed under The MIT License (MIT).
# See included LICENSE file or the notice below.
#
# Copyright © 2016 Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
# in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
# SOFTWARE.
import gi
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import GLib as glib
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import Gio
from gi.repository import Notify
from collections import OrderedDict
# from collections import OrderedDict
import urllib.parse
import subprocess
import copy
import shutil
import dbus
import math
import json
import os

class FilesIndicator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = appindicator.Indicator.new(
            'files-indicator', "document-open-recent",
            appindicator.IndicatorCategory.HARDWARE
        )
        self.user_home = os.path.expanduser('~')
        filename = '.pinned_files.json'
        self.pinned_list = os.path.join(self.user_home,filename)

        self.config = os.path.join(self.user_home,'.files_indicator.json')
        self.max_items = 15
        self.name_length = 20
        self.read_config()

        self.app.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)

        self.cached_files = self.get_recent_files()
        self.make_menu()
        self.update()

    def read_config(self,*args):
        config = {}
        try:
            with open(self.config) as f:
                 config = json.load(f)

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('>>> ',self.config,' not found.Creating one')
            f = open(self.config,'w')
            config = {'max_items':self.max_items,
                      'name_length':self.name_length
            }
            json.dump(config,f,indent=4)
            f.close()
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            print(">>> Can't read ",self.pinned_list,',may be corrupt')
            return None
        else:
            self.max_items = config['max_items']
            self.name_length = config['name_length']

    def add_menu_item(self, menu_obj, item_type, image, label, action, args):
        """ dynamic function that can add menu items depending on
            the item type and other arguments"""
        menu_item, icon = None, None
        if item_type is gtk.ImageMenuItem and label:
            menu_item = gtk.ImageMenuItem.new_with_label(label)
            menu_item.set_always_show_image(True)
            if '/' in image:
                icon = gtk.Image.new_from_file(image)
            else:
                icon = gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(image, 48)
            menu_item.set_image(icon)
        elif item_type is gtk.ImageMenuItem and not label:
            menu_item = gtk.ImageMenuItem()
            menu_item.set_always_show_image(True)
            if '/' in image:
                icon = gtk.Image.new_from_file(image)
            else:
                icon = gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(image, 16)
            menu_item.set_image(icon)
        elif item_type is gtk.MenuItem:
            menu_item = gtk.MenuItem(label)
        elif item_type is gtk.SeparatorMenuItem:
            menu_item = gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        if action:
            menu_item.connect('activate', action, *args)

        menu_obj.append(menu_item)
        menu_item.show()

    def get_user_dirs(self,*args):
        user_dirs = []
        for index,val in glib.UserDirectory.__enum_values__.items():
            if index == 8: continue
            dir = glib.get_user_special_dir(index)
            if dir: user_dirs.append(dir)
        return user_dirs

    def get_file_icon(self,*args):
        if args[-1].endswith('.desktop'):
            desk_file = Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new_from_filename(args[-1])
            icon = desk_file.get_icon()
            if type(icon) == Gio.ThemedIcon:
                themed_name = icon.get_names()[0]
                theme = gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
                name = theme.lookup_icon(themed_name, 48, 0).get_filename()
            if type(icon) == Gio.FileIcon:
                name = icon.get_file().get_uri()

            icon_url= urllib.parse.unquote(name).replace('file://','') 
            return icon_url

        file = Gio.File.new_for_path(args[-1])
        file_info = file.query_info("standard::*",0)
        icon_string = file_info.get_icon().to_string()
        if 'folder-' in icon_string:
            return icon_string.split()[-2]
        return icon_string.split()[-1]

    def get_recent_files(self,*args):
        manager = gtk.RecentManager.get_default()
        try:
            files = OrderedDict()
            for index,item in enumerate(manager.get_items(),1):
                    uri = item.get_uri()
                    uri_decoded = urllib.parse.unquote(uri)
                    filepath = uri_decoded.replace('file://','')
                    if not os.path.exists(filepath): continue
                    basename = os.path.basename(uri_decoded)
                    files[basename] = filepath
                    if index == self.max_items:
                        break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return None
        finally:  return files

    def callback(self,*args):
        self.update()

    def update(self,*args):
        current_files = self.get_recent_files()
        if current_files != self.cached_files:
             self.make_menu()
             self.cached_files = current_files
        glib.timeout_add_seconds(3,self.callback)

    def add_submenu(self,top_menu,label):
        menuitem = gtk.MenuItem(label)
        submenu = gtk.Menu()
        menuitem.set_submenu(submenu)
        top_menu.append(menuitem)
        menuitem.show()
        return submenu

    def make_menu(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'app_menu'):
            for item in self.app_menu.get_children():
                    self.app_menu.remove(item)
        else:
            self.app_menu = gtk.Menu()
        recent = self.add_submenu(self.app_menu,'Recent Files')
        recent_dict = self.get_recent_files()

        content = [recent,gtk.ImageMenuItem,'gtk-add',
                   'Add to Recent Files',self.add_recent,[None]
        ]      
        self.add_menu_item(*content) 

        content = [recent,gtk.ImageMenuItem,'user-trash',
                   'Clear recent files list',self.clear_recent,[None]
        ]      
        self.add_menu_item(*content)

        content = [recent,gtk.SeparatorMenuItem,
                   None,None,
                   None,[None]
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)
        self.add_menu_item(*content) 
        if not recent_dict:
            content = [recent,gtk.MenuItem,None,
                       'No items',None,None
            ]
            self.add_menu_item(*content)
            last = None
            for i in recent.get_children():
                last = i
            last.set_sensitive(False)
        else:
            for name,data in recent_dict.items():
                icon = self.get_file_icon(data)
                content = [recent, gtk.ImageMenuItem,
                           icon, name[:self.name_length],
                           self.open_item, [data]
                ]
                self.add_menu_item(*content)

        # Pinned files
        bookmarks = self.add_submenu(self.app_menu,'Pinned Files')
        content = [bookmarks,gtk.ImageMenuItem,
                   'bookmark_add','Pin a file',
                   self.pin_file,[bookmarks,None]
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)

        content = [bookmarks,gtk.ImageMenuItem,
                   'remove','Remove item',
                   self.remove_pinned,['files']
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)

        content = [bookmarks,gtk.ImageMenuItem,
                   'user-trash','Remove All',
                   self.remove_all_pinned,[None]
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)
        content = [bookmarks,gtk.SeparatorMenuItem,
                   None,None,
                   None,[None]
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)
        self.add_menu_item(*content) 

        pinned_files = self.get_pinned()

        if (pinned_files and 
            'files' in pinned_files.keys() and
            pinned_files['files']):
            for filepath in pinned_files['files']:
                icon = self.get_file_icon(filepath) 
                content = [bookmarks,gtk.ImageMenuItem,
                           icon,os.path.basename(filepath),
                           self.open_item,[filepath]
                ]
                self.add_menu_item(*content)
        else:
            content = [bookmarks,gtk.MenuItem,None,
                       'No items',None,None
            ]
            self.add_menu_item(*content)
            last = None
            for i in bookmarks.get_children():
                last = i
            last.set_sensitive(False)

        places = self.add_submenu(self.app_menu,'Places')
        content = [places,gtk.ImageMenuItem,'add',
                   'Pin Directory',self.pin_dir,[None]
        ]

        self.add_menu_item(*content)

        content = [places,gtk.ImageMenuItem,
                   'remove','Remove Pinned',
                   self.remove_pinned,['dirs']
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)

        content = [places,gtk.SeparatorMenuItem,
                   None,None,
                   None,[None]
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)

        content = [places,gtk.MenuItem,None,
                   'Standard Dirs',None,None
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)
        last = None
        for i in places.get_children():
            last = i
        last.set_sensitive(False)
        for dir in self.get_user_dirs():
            icon = self.get_file_icon(dir)
            content = [places,gtk.ImageMenuItem,icon,
                       os.path.basename(dir),self.open_item,[dir]

            ]
            self.add_menu_item(*content)

        content = [places,gtk.SeparatorMenuItem,
                   None,None,
                   None,[None]
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)

        content = [places,gtk.MenuItem,None,
                   'Pinned Dirs',None,None
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)
        last = None
        for i in places.get_children():
            last = i
        last.set_sensitive(False)

        if (pinned_files and 
           'dirs' in pinned_files.keys() and
           pinned_files['dirs']):
            for dir in pinned_files['dirs']:
                icon = self.get_file_icon(dir)
                print(icon)
                content = [places,gtk.ImageMenuItem,icon,
                           os.path.basename(dir),self.open_item,[dir]

                ]
                self.add_menu_item(*content)
        else:
            content = [places,gtk.MenuItem,None,
                       'No items',None,None
            ]
            self.add_menu_item(*content)
            last = None
            for i in places.get_children():
                last = i
            last.set_sensitive(False)

        content = [self.app_menu,gtk.SeparatorMenuItem,
                   None,None,
                   None,[None]
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)
        content = [self.app_menu,gtk.ImageMenuItem,'exit',
                   'quit',self.quit,[None]
        ]
        self.add_menu_item(*content)
        self.app.set_menu(self.app_menu)

    def check_directory(self,*args):
        current_set = set(os.listdir(args[-1]))
        return current_set - self.cached_set


    def get_pinned(self,*args):
        try:
            with open(self.pinned_list) as f:
                 return json.load(f,object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('>>> ',self.pinned_list,' not found')
            return None
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            print(">>> Can't read ",self.pinned_list,',may be corrupt')
            return None

    def pin_dir(self,*args):
        # TODO
        current_list = self.get_pinned()
        if not current_list:
                current_list = OrderedDict()
                current_list['dirs'] = []
                f = open(self.pinned_list,'w')
                f.write("")
                f.close()

        if not args[-1]:
                cmd = "zenity --file-selection --directory --separator || --multiple"
                dirs = self.run_cmd(cmd.split())
        else:
                dirs = args[-1]

        dir_list = []
        if not dirs: return None
        dir_list = dirs.decode().strip().split("||")
        if not 'dirs' in current_list.keys():
             current_list['dirs'] = []
        for f in dir_list:
                #icon = self.get_file_icon(f)
                current_list['dirs'].append(f)

        with open(self.pinned_list,'w') as f:
                json.dump(current_list,f,indent=4)
        self.make_menu()

    def pin_file(self,*args):
        current_list = self.get_pinned()
        if not current_list:
                current_list = OrderedDict()
                current_list['files'] = []
                f = open(self.pinned_list,'w')
                f.write("")
                f.close()
        if not args[-1]:
                cmd = "zenity --file-selection --separator || --multiple "
                files = self.run_cmd(cmd.split())
        else:
                files = args[-1]

        file_list = []
        if not files: return None
        file_list = files.decode().strip().split("||")
        if not 'files' in current_list.keys():
            current_list['files'] = []
        for f in file_list:
                #icon = self.get_file_icon(f)
                current_list['files'].append(f)

        with open(self.pinned_list,'w') as f:
                json.dump(current_list,f,indent=4)
        self.make_menu()

    def remove_all_pinned(self,*args):
        try:
            #os.unlink(self.pinned_list)

            with open(self.pinned_list) as f:
                pinned = json.load(f)
            pinned.pop('files')       
            with open(self.pinned_list,'w') as f:
                    json.dump(pinned,f,indent=4)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            self.make_menu()

    def remove_pinned(self,*args):
        key = args[-1]
        pinned = self.get_pinned() 
        if not pinned: return
        cmd_str = "zenity --forms --add-combo Remove --combo-values"
        vals = "|".join(pinned[key])
        cmd = cmd_str.split() + [vals]
        item = self.run_cmd(cmd)
        if item: 
            path = item.decode().strip()
            index = pinned[key].index(path)
            pinned[key].pop(index)
            with open(self.pinned_list,'w') as f:
                json.dump(pinned,f,indent=4)
            self.make_menu()

    def add_recent(self,*args):
        cmd = "zenity --file-selection --separator || --multiple "
        files = self.run_cmd(cmd.split())
        file_list = []
        if not files: return
        file_list = files.decode().strip().split("||")
        items = ['file://' + f for f in file_list]
        for f in items: gtk.RecentManager().get_default().add_item(f)

    def clear_recent(self,*args):
        try:
            gtk.RecentManager.get_default().purge_items()
            self.make_menu()
        except:
            pass

    def open_item(self,*args):
        #self.run_cmd(['xdg-open',args[-1]]) 
        if args[-1].endswith('.desktop'):
            desk_file = Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new_from_filename(args[-1])
            return desk_file.launch_uris()
        return subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open',args[-1]])

    def quit(self,*args):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def run_cmd(self, cmdlist):
        """ utility: reusable function for running external commands """
        #new_env = dict(os.environ)
        #new_env['LC_ALL'] = 'C'
        try:
            stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist) #env=new_env)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            pass
        else:
            if stdout:
                return stdout

    def run(self):
        """ Launches the indicator """
        try:
            gtk.main()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

    def quit(self, *args):
        """ closes indicator """
        gtk.main_quit()


def main():
    """ defines program entry point """
    indicator = FilesIndicator()
    indicator.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    main()
  except  KeyboardInterrupt:
    gtk.main_quit()
```

#### Configurations

The indicator is configured via two json files stored in user's home directory.

`~/.files_indicator.json` controls user interface , the length of menu entries and maximum numbers in the Recent Files Menu.

```
{
    "name_length": 30,
    "max_items": 10
}
```

The `~/.pinned_files.json` controls the lists of pinned files and folders. Each item is a list/array.

```
{
    "dirs": [
        "/home/xieerqi/\u56fe\u7247/Wallpapers"
    ],
    "files": [
        "/home/xieerqi/work_in_progress/videonauth_code.py",
        "/home/xieerqi/work_in_progress/spin_button.py"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wow, impressed that you created a solution to this problem too! :D

Comment: @Ads20000 Thanks :) This indicator originally was meant to be only for recent files. When I saw the question I thought the feature would be nice to add to the indicator ,too, plus it was very simple to implement - took me pretty much one morning and 2 cups of coffee :)

Comment: Your work also made it into an [OMG! Ubuntu! article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/places-indicator-applet-ubuntu-unity-desktop?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+d0od+%28OMG%21+Ubuntu%21%29)! :D

Comment: Yep, i saw that :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys what I did was just installing Ubuntu-Gnome and enable the 'Places' extension in Tweak tool and got it. Gotta say Ubuntu Gnome looks much more better than Unity

[image: See the "Lugares" tab]

Comment: Wise choice. It was apparent from the beginning you're leaning towards using GNOME, since it's more familiar to you from CentOS. What they use in CentOS is GNOME Flashback, by the way. It's meant to be visually similar to previous version yet use newer technology. As for Unity, it might not be for everyone, though I personally dislike GNOME a lot for their constant removal of features and making development complex.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I'm kinda "noob" into Linux or "outdated" as you prefer to say it. I mean, I've always used a terminal for servers on CentOS, and not much of graphic stuff, I didn't know there were different graphical options such as Unity and Gnome, I just thought Ubuntu can only look the way it does from the ubuntu.com download package, CentOS the way it does from the official webpage, etc. Didn't know there were different graphical choices you can have. Good to keep on learning. @Serg

Comment: Let me ask you this question: If you absolutely had to use Unity desktop, which other things you wish it had ? ( Obviously, I'm trying to research ideas for future uses :)

Comment: the only thing I can think of is the "Places" tab or "Applications" (which  I don't really use) the rest is available in Unity too I guess, what I don't like from gnome is that for applications menu you have to click on a button on most of programs (the typical file, edit, etc menu)