# How to modify or customize Ubuntu panel like you can in Mate?

Tags: 16.04, unity, panel

Is there is any application or command options to customize the Ubuntu panel like in Mate (i.e, processor indicator, network indicator,CPU, and memory usage indicator)?

Here is an example of the Mate customization panel:
[image: Mate Tweak panel]

Comment: You use MATE. That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do so in Unity - its panel is static. If you want to have places/applications icons, you'll have to install indicators made specifically for that purpose. Here's a couple:

- [Places indicator question](https://askubuntu.com/q/850930/295286)
- [Classic Menu indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/46811/295286) (This post is slightly outdated as the indicator is already in default Ubuntu repositories, so `sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator)