# How can I pin a specific document so I can access it easily and frequently?

Tags: nautilus, files, gui, ubuntu-dock

In Ubuntu, you can mark certain applications as your favorite, and in the file explorer, you can drag folders to the left sidebar. But I can't seem to add a bookmark for a specific file, nor can I set a file to open from the Ubuntu dock at the left of the screen.

What is a good option to have a document in a place where you will remember its importance on a frequent basis?

Comment: Put a link to it in your desktop or home directory?

Comment: @muru That's probably as good as an answer.

Comment: @MaxLi Btw, "best way" is highly subjective, so you might want to edit your answer to state specifically what are your needs. Do you want the file to be on the dock ? In nautilus file manager panel ? In the top panel ? Maybe on desktop, as muru suggested ?

Comment: Something similar: I have a number of files and folders whose locations I frequently forget. I created a Links directory in my home directory and put symlinks in it to things I have trouble finding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An alternative for simpler files is to use **Nautilus** file manager to create a link and move it to the desktop.

For your word processing, spreadsheet and presentation documents you can navigate using Nautilus to the directory containing the file. Then right click on the the file and select `Make Link` a new icon appears called `Link to filename`. Grab this and drag it to your desktop.

Below is an animation for a word processing document called `eyesome.odt` and a desktop link created for it:

[image: make link.gif]

After the link is dragged to the desktop, simply double click on it and the application associated with it automatically opens it.

---

### Keyboard shortcut method <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Click</kbd>

A quicker method is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Click</kbd> on the file and drag a copy to the desktop.

The subtle difference is the Desktop name is no longer "Link to filename" but simply "filename".

Comment: You can also drag the file to the target location while holding Ctrl-Shift to create a link.

Comment: Wallpaper checks out.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of pinning a file, let's switch gears: pin a command that opens the file. That's easily achieved via [creating a .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/q/854373/295286), which is what those icons on the dock actually are. Sufficient enough would be to have file in `~/.local/share/applications/` called `importantfile.desktop` and with contents maybe like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=gedit /etc/passwd
Name=Open Important Thing
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/status/messagebox_critical.png
```

The `Icon=` part is optional, but as you can see you can use standard gnome icons. Remember also to use your own favorite program to open the important file - `Exec=gedit /etc/passwd` is just an example.

Alternative (and a very biased solution, as I am the author of that) is to use [Files Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/851165/295286), which besides other things allows pinning specific files to be shown in the indicator itself and are opened by whatever default program is set for their respective filetypes.

Comment: Perhaps adding something like the following before the last paragraph would be nice for completion (for Ubuntu 17.10 and later with GNOME 3): `Then you would be able to search and find "*Open Important Thing*" in *Activities* overview and then pin it to the dock by right-clicking and selecting "Add to Favourites".`

Comment: Also `xdg-open` or something similar in place of `gedit` in the `Exec=` line?

Comment: @pomsky  Yes, `xdg-open` can work, but for some files that aren't in database it's just easier to use specific app. But yes, good point