# Adding files to Ubuntu dock

Tags: shortcuts, ubuntu-dock, document

I need to access some of my files really fast, so I have some shortcuts on my Desktop,  but I want them even faster so I prefer to have a shortcut to my files just in the dock, panel, or somewhere like that.

In Ubuntu 18.04 (using GNOME) is there any way to add a shortcut to a specific file or document to the Ubuntu dock?

As my question is marked as a duplicate to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067008) I need to clarify that I want my files on the dock not on the desktop etc.

Comment: that question is about having shortcuts to specific files on the desktop. I want them in the dock

Comment: No it's not, read carefully and check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067010/480481). Create a `.desktop` file as instructed and then you would be able to search and find "*Open Important Thing*" (or whatever name you use) in *Activities* overview. Then you would be able to pin it to the dock by right-clicking and selecting "Add to Favourites".