# LibreOffice shows many icons on the Launcher, what can I do about this?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, libreoffice

When I run LibreOffice it shows another icon at the launcher. If I open new files it will keep showing new icons for each file.

When I run it from the terminal it does not return any error messages.

Here's the image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone else posted I do not see this issue. I see the following when opening lots of new files of the same application i.e. Writer, Calc, Draw, Impress.

[image: lo multifile]

I think the needs clarification but it could be a bug and make sure you are installing from Natty's official repository and not an old PPA.

The only thing I can add is that I have a custom [libreoffice launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/which-custom-unity-launchers-and-quicklists-do-you-use/36375#36375), hence the white writer icon.

Comment: But i have two different icons for writer and not just one. I understand that each component of the libreoffice has its own, and looks better like that. In your screenshot i can see that Calc has 3 files open, but in my case it would be calc's icon plus another icon representing 3 spreadsheets. As you can see i got writer icon as the 3rd one and another below system monitor in the 11th position.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. It's probably a bug in LO handling of Unity launchers and looks similar to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/744640)

Comment: Actually see bug [753304](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/753304)

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any identical icons in the sidebar, it will open separate icons for LibreOffice Writer, Calc, Impress because they are all separate programs. Is this what you mean? Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

It's meant to do that, I'm not sure of a work-around to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

Each new opened file in LibroOffice will have its own icon on the sidebar. It's exactly as OpenOffice was used to do in ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour, even if it seems a bit odd. LibreOffice/OpenOffice create separate windows for every document, and unity tracks each window as a separate window due to the way LibreOffice reports itself to the window manager. Hopefully this problem will go away in future versions of LibreOffice, but unfortunately there is nothing you can do at this point, other than maybe grouping the windows with the compiz plugin, *(which may not actually group the icons on the launcher - I cannot be sure because I have not tested this as yet)*.

Comment: But I already have the writer icons at the launcher, and files that are opened are being shown in another as you can see in the image near the mouse. For an example, if i open 5 files at Gedit i'll have them all grouped with the Gedit icon, and not in a different icon.

Comment: I updated the image http://ubuntuone.com/p/ppx/

Answer (score 0):

Well I must say that this behaviour it's normal on LibreOffice 3.3. In fact it happen to me some times, **but...** ***([see the image attached, sorry, too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkO4S.png))***

I've just install LibreOffice 3.4 from libreoffice page 'cause there isn't any PPA yet. And everything it's fine, I've installed [lo-menu extension for LibreOffice](http://ubuntuone.com/p/z0o/) *(not deb)* and App Menu works fine, but when I open a Document *(from writer icon, from libreoffice center)* the upcoming new icon have not "Icon"..

Maybe 'cause the *.desktop files on `/usr/share/applications/` are only links to `/opt/libreoffice3.4/share/xdg/`. So I've tryed *drag 'n drop* the *.desktop files to my Launcher, and same behaviuor; I've tryed replacing the links files on */usr/share/applications/* with the *.desktop files from */opt/libreoffice3.4/share/xdg/* and the same.

It could be perfect if no extra icon open next to Writer, Calc's one, but will be fine if the next icons opened it has an icon.

Any idea or suggestion?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkO4S.png):