# How to quicklist for DeaDBeeF?

Tags: 11.04, unity, quicklists

How to add quicklist lines to **deadbeef.desktop** file ?
Because it's my favorite music player ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Deadbeef quicklist is OK.http://i.imgur.com/MsGHY.png

Comment: DeaDBeeF new release: 0.5.0.. This release includes quicklist feature for unity icon    https://launchpad.net/~alexey-smirnov/+archive/deadbeef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may already know the basics of quicklists, but I figured I'd better be thorough anyway

1. Copy launcher file to your home directory:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/deadbeef.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the file for editing in gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/deadbeef.desktop
   ```
3. Add this text to the bottom of the file, then close and save:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Play;Pause;Stop;Next;Prev
   [Play Shortcut Group]
   Name=Play
   Exec=deadbeef --play
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Pause Shortcut Group]
   Name=Pause
   Exec=deadbeef --pause
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Stop Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop
   Exec=deadbeef --stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Next Shortcut Group]
   Name=Next
   Exec=deadbeef --next
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Prev Shortcut Group]
   Name=Prev
   Exec=deadbeef --prev
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

There are a few other commands in `deadbeef -h` but these are the only ones that I thought made sense to add.

Comment: Please add it to http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity.