# Drawer or other organisation for hundreds of scripts in Unity Launcher

Tags: unity, lenses

I have a large number of .sh scripts for opening ssh connections to various remote machines. These .sh scripts are grouped by staging/test/production/etc

In Gnome I had a series of entries in the Places menu, one for each type of system:

```
Places
|
+ Staging
|       +Machine 1
|       +Machine 2
|       +Machine 3
+Test
|       +Machine 4
|       +Machine 5
```

What are my options for having this kind of layout in the Unity launcher? I suppose I'm really looking for a drawer or similar that I can mouse over to find the correct script.

If I had only a few scripts I could just pin them to the launcher one by one, but I've got about 200!

Perhaps there is a Lens for doing this?

Comment: Only as an alternative: I use Remmina (http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) for remote-connections. Maybe it's useful for you too?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the ssh launcher to have a quicklist with all your machines. See [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/35523#35523) .

Comment: That is what I did. You could make more than 1 launcher for each group (staging, test etc).

Comment: Maybe you could script something to create the ssh quicklist based on all the connections you have in your sh scripts. When you need more connections you could just recreate your quicklist.

Comment: That would be awesome. Especially if it did it in a conventional way, for instance by parsing .ssh/config. That would be a nice addition to the ssh quicklist.

Comment: Good call Egil +1 on your comment. I might give it a shot myself; been dying to start again with some python coding but have not found anything fun :-D

Answer (score 2):

Try [Drawers](https://launchpad.net/drawers) for an easy (drag-n-drop) way to create custom launchers. It's an app I wrote to bundle together different launchers or shortcuts for files, weblinks, etc. It's easy to edit contents names and execution lines once they're added to the drawer (right-click items and choose Edit Properties).

Here's a [video](http://vimeo.com/56953537) I recently created to show its usage.

Here's what it looks like when you open a drawer:

[image]

Any items you add to the drawer will be available also through Quicklists (right-clicking the launcher) so opening a drawer isn't even necessary.

I will be releasing a new version shortly (13.1.1) that has a number of improvements including launching applications in terminals.

To install add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install drawers
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you really don't want to move away from the old menu you were once used to, you could simply use the "Classic Menu Indicator" (For Ubuntu 12.04/11.10/11.04). I found instructions on how to [install it here](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/indicators-collection-for-ubuntu.html).