# Google services launcher icon

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, google

I have added a custom launcher for common services like Gmail etc in Unity.
[Google Services Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/37764#37764)

Where can I get the Google services icon?  In another theme? I'm using default for 11.04.

Comment: Did you mean to link to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/35489#35489) instead?

Answer (score 2):

I created the launcher and downloaded the icon from a website. You can download that icon [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4697206/Google.tar.gz).In link I have provided 4 icons for the google services. You can choose whichever one you like.

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to the instructions for customizing launchers?  Right now I've got a Google services launcher that looks pretty plain.