# How do I create a dynamic quicklist for the home folder?

Tags: unity, quicklists

How can i create a dynamic quicklist for the home folder  which adds all the bookmarks as quicklists (i heard it is possible via libunity) ?

Comment: You might be interested in [Places Indicator](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators/42432#42432) until a solution with quicklists is found.

Comment: @Cas really nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a small shell script that updates your Home-Quicklist with all
>   your bookmarks. No manual manipulation. It reads your bookmark file
>   and creates the menu items from it. It also adds the "Root
>   Filemanager" menu entry.
>
> [image: Screenshot of the quicklist in action]
>
> 1. Copy the script listed below into an empty file and put it in your
>      scripts-folder (we will assume that is `~/bin/` and the script name
>      you choose is `unityhome.bash`).
> 2. Run the script once to add the entries:
>
>    ```
>    bash ~/bin/unityhome.bash
>    ```
> 3. Optionally you may have cron run the script for you every once in
>      a while. To add it to cron, type the follwing command into a shell:
>
>    ```
>    crontab -e An editor will open. There add a line like:
>
>    @reboot /bin/bash/ $HOME/bin/unityhome.bash > /dev/null 2>&1
>    ```
>
>    If you don't do this step, you'll have to run the script by hand every
>      time you change your nautilus bookmarks if you want the quicklist
>      updated.
> 4. Changes only take effect on your next login or after you Alt+F2
>
>    ```
>    unity --replace So do that. *Note: Don't run `unity --replace`
>    ```
>
>    in a terminal. If you close that terminal, it will kill unity with
>      it.*
> 5. Enjoy and have a look at the [similar script for
>      gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/44657#44657) that parses your ssh bookmarks (in
>      `~/.ssh/config`).
>
> Script:
>   ------- Here is the script:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # tabsize: 4, encoding: utf8
> #
> # © 2011 con-f-use@gmx.net. Use permitted under MIT license:
> #     http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
> # 
> # CONTRIBUTORS: Chris Druif <cyber.druif@gmail.com>
> #               Scott Severance <http://www.scottseverance.us/>
> # 
> # This script updates the unity quicklist menu for nautilus to
> ```
>
> contain the user
>       # bookmarks. The updates will have efect after unity is restarted
>   (either on
>       # the next login or by invoking 'unity --replace').
>
> ```
> # location of template and unity bar launchers
> nautempl="/usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop"
> target="$HOME/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop"
> bookmarks="$HOME/.gtk-bookmarks"
>
> # backup if file already exists
> if [ -e "$target" ]; then
>     echo "Creating backup of: $target."
>     mv -n "$target" "$target.bak"
> fi
>
> # copy template
> cp "$nautempl" "$target"
>
> sed -i "s/\(OnlyShowIn=GNOME;\)/\1Unity;/" "$target"
>
> echo "X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=" >> $target
>
> bmcount=0
> while read bmline; do
>     bmcount=$(($bmcount+1))     # number of current bookmark
>     bmname=${bmline#*\ }        # name of the bookmark
>     bmpath=${bmline%%\ *}       # path the bookmark leads to
>     # deal with bookmarks that have no name
>     if [ "$bmname" = "$bmpath" ]; then
>         bmname=${bmpath##*/}
>     fi
>     # fix spaces in names and paths
>     bmname="$(echo "$bmname" | sed 's/%20/ /g')"
>     bmpath="$(echo "$bmpath" | sed 's/%20/ /g')"
>     # extend shortcut list with current bookmark
>     sed -i
> ```
>
> "s/(X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=.*)/\1Scg${bmcount};/" "$target"
>           # write bookmark information
>           cat - >> "$target" <
>
> ```
> [Scg$bmcount Shortcut Group]
> Name=$bmname
> Exec=nautilus "$bmpath"
> OnlyShowIn=Unity
> EOF
> done < "$bookmarks"
>
> # Add a root file manager entry
> sed -i "s/\(X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=.*\)/\1RootFM;/" "$target"
> cat - >> "$target" <<EOF
>
> [RootFM Shortcut Group]
> Name=Root
> Exec=gksudo nautilus
> OnlyShowIn=Unity
> EOF
>
> exit 0
> ```

**[Original Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/43150#43150) - Written by [con-f-use](https://askubuntu.com/users/17789/con-f-use)**

Answer (score 2):

FYI
The API is explained on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Dynamic%20Quicklist%20entries)

```
Dynamic Quicklist entries

Quicklists may also be created and appended to the launcher. To create a quicklist 
a root node must first be created as a container, and then child nodes are added
to it. This final result may be packed into the launcher which is then 
shipped over the bus to Unity. Updates to the quicklist are also live.
Rather than describe the entire API, an example of using quicklist (as well as 
progress and count) is provided below using the vala bindings.

It is important to note that the main loop must be invoked for the program to 
actual work. Libunity requires the usage of the main loop as work may be done 
async.
```

I have not seen an example of this yet. If I do I will add it here within an hour ;)

Dynamic quicklists did NOT work prior to unity - 3.8.8-0ubuntu1 due to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/729074).

Comment: 1 hour later... I have not found any example of this. Sorry :-(

Comment: An example for you: [Opera dynamic quicklist](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/41228#41228)