# I need documentation on how to create quicklists

Tags: documentation, language-support, quicklists

Can someone please tell me the language used for quicklists, and where I can find its documentation? I know you can copy a similar quicklist and modify it, but that approach has serious limitations.

Comment: Care to expand on "has serious limitations"? I have seen someone make a quicklist for Opera by using a python script. Check the 2nd Opera link in this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity

Answer (score 7):

Static quicklists don't require a specific programming languages But if you are looking for syntax it is as follows

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Quicklist1;Quicklist2;Quicklist3

[Qucklist1 Shortcut Group]
Name=Quicklist1 
Exec=Executable command
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Qucklist2 Shortcut Group]
Name=Quicklist2
Exec=Executable command
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Qucklist3 Shortcut Group]
Name=Quicklist3 
Exec=Executable command
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

There is more on that [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Quicklists). That page also has information (with example code) for how to create dynamic quicklists, which let the program dynamically create quicklists on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easyest way is by installing Ubuntu-tweak which has a Unity quicklist editor: http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Tuete! Even though your post does answer the question, we always like to post informative answers here on Ask Ubuntu. For example, how can we install Ubuntu-tweak? What are the commands, if any? Where exactly is this Unity quicklist editor? Are there any screenshots? We also don't like just posting links (like you did), because links can die, so people won't be able to find out what's behind that link if it does. You can always [edit] your answer to include more information by clicking on the `edit` link right underneath the text of your answer. Thanks!