# Can I disable Ubuntu One syncing for open documents?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

A standard feature of most of the document editors like TexMaker or Kile is auto-saving as you type.  Of course this is generally considered a good thing, but if I'm editing a document that's already synced with Ubuntu One, Ubuntu One syncs the file every time the editor auto-saves.  In addition to eating resources, this also usually results in u1conflict files, and at some point I have to log into Ubuntu One via a web browser to remove the file (there are problems building the pdf from the tex source otherwise).

I know I can temporarily disable Ubuntu One, or temporarily move the document being edited to a folder that's not synced, but it's a bit of a pain to have to take these extra steps every time I want to work on a paper.  Is there some way to maybe write a script to disable Ubuntu One automatically while a file is open, and wait until I'm finished editing before syncing?

Comment: This was a bug we believe is fixed in natty. Have you tried it there?

Comment: @Chipaca is there a workaround for other versions? I don't think it should be necessary to upgrade just to include a single bugfix.

Comment: I'm using natty.  So far I haven't had problems with u1conflict files, but it's still a bit annoying to have a series of pop-up notifications every time I compile the pdf, so I'm still disabling Ubuntu One, or temporarily moving my files to a non-synced folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Ubuntu One Quicklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/47087#47087) to temporary disable the Ubuntu One syncdaemon while you are working on a document. It is not exactly the solution you were searching for but it might make your life easier.

Comment: if the OP doesn't want to upgrade, he can't make use of the quicklists.

Comment: Are quicklists only available for Oneric?  I thought I saw a post on OMG! Ubuntu explaining how to get them working on Natty.  I'm not a programmer/developer but I'm not entirely incompetent as far as following someone's CLI instructions goes.  I'm flagging this as answering my question since it gives me a reason to get quicklists working on my machine, which is something I've been meaning to try anyway.

Comment: @Uri - I was able to follow the instructions in the link with no trouble - took about one minute.  Not sure why the upgrade is needed.

Answer (score 0):

@Chipaca. No, I can easily mess up my U1 when I work with latex editors such as Kile. The syncdaemon will get incredibly confused and I went back to disabling U1 before I start working with Kile. Still, after some latex editing my pc needs sometimes hours to sync a few kb of data.