# Can I create a quicklist sub-menu?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, quicklists

Can I create a quicklist sub-menu for my launchers? Like if I put Ubuntu and on hover it opened a sub-menu with all my Ubuntu links?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about creating a custom launcher called 'Ubuntu' that would have a list of urls (quicklist)? [more info](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity)

Comment: No I've already created that. Say for instance OMG! Ubuntu was replaced with Ubuntu. When I hover over it like my picture it would open up another menu with more choices.

Comment: Not possible @wojox. You have 1 dimension to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sorry the quicklists are basic 1-dimensional  text lists.

Comment: meh, well thanks. I know there now called quicklists. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, but it should soon become rather easy to make a lense for that kind of functionality. We can expect lots of lenses to become available during the lifetime of 11.10.