# How do I open multiple terminals?

Tags: 11.04, command-line

I just downloaded Ubuntu 11.04 and as far as I can remember, there was the option of opening multiple terminals in tabs in Ubuntu. I cannot discover this feature in 11.04. Also, as a general query, suppose I open emacs from the terminal, then I wouldn't be able to do anything else on that terminal as long as I have emacs running, so what is a good way to multi-task?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out Terminator as well. It's in the repo's

[image]

Answer (score 20):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> will open a new terminal window if you are already working in the terminal, alternatively you can just select "Open Terminal" form the file menu as well.

And like @Alex said you can open a new tab by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: At least in Ubuntu 12.10, it's **CTRL + SHIFT + T** and Alex's answer states the same. Maybe you mistyped?

Comment: Perhaps... I don't know, this was such a long time, and I am not on an Ubuntu box to confirm whether it works or not...

Comment: @its_me I just used the command CTRL+Shift+N it works fine c:

Answer (score 13):

right click on mouse and select open tab.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You may open a new tab by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, or go to `File ->`New tab`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the terminal back after you open Emacs or any other gui:

1. Return to the terminal (click on the terminal window)
2. Press Ctrl-Z
3. Run the command `bg` to unfreeze the gui

See also the `jobs` and `fg` commands.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a terminal multiplexer like `byobu` or `tmux`. Byobu is beautifully configured for Ubuntu out of the box. Tmux requires some initial configuration, but is (relatively) easy to customize. Think of it as a command-line program that can run multiple shells organised like tabs.

I prefer to use a terminal multiplexer over gnome-terminal tabs because I can detach and attach from anywhere. Examples:

- Login to work via ssh, start a multiplexer with a few tabs. Open a file with emacs, start a huge download, etc. Detach the multiplexer, logout of ssh, go to work. Reattach your session and resume work right where you left it: emacs stayed open, your download continued while you drove to work.
- Start writing your research paper (in LaTeX of course ;) on your desktop. Realise it's far too nice a day to be sitting indoors. Reattach the multiplexer session on your lappy outside and continue working.

Answer (score 1):

There a [Terminal Quicklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/39532#39532) that has the option to open new tab.

Although it's not a new tab you can use the **middle mouse** on the launcher to open a new terminal.

I would also recommend you look into [Tmux](http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/06/28/tmux-the-terminal-multiplexer/) as this is a great tool for working in a single terminal screen. For example it will keep your session running after you logout from remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

mssh - simple and effective, allows one to issue the same commands to all windows, i.e. to each ssh session.