# What is this file(bamf-2.index)?

Tags: filesystem

I have found out this file while learning about Ubuntu file system today under the location `/usr/share/applications/`.

What actually is the purpose of this file. Googling doesn't pop up anything I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a file for the `bamfdaemon`. Also called Window matching library - daemon. bamf matches application windows to desktop files

This package contains the daemon used by the library and a gio 
module that facilitates the matching of applications started 
through GDesktopAppInfo

> When you open a program, Unity will either pop up a new icon on the
>   launcher(dock) and/or add an arrow to an existing icon. Each icon is
>   not an executable; it is a .desktop file.
>
> bamfdaemon helps unity to determe whether an arrow needs to be added
>   to an existing icon, or a new icon be popped up, along with other
>   behaviors dependent on application identity.

Read answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45702/all-browsers-with-one-icon-in-the-launcher) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260734/what-does-bamfdaemon-do) for more info.