# Can I add wine application category list to unity dash?

Tags: unity, wine, unity-dash

In the dropdown list of application categories wine is missing and so all wine applications are missing as well. How can I add wine applications to the application category?

Answer (score 1):

You can install cardapio which gives you a launcher that shows the original app categories.

https://launchpad.net/cardapio
[image: open launchere]

see the answers to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47976/how-can-i-get-a-more-traditional-drop-down-like-menu-for-unity)

Answer (score 0):

While not necessarily a method to get Wine applications into the Dash, I have a suggestion relative to the menu system.  Before I get into that, let me just say that Wine applications do show up in my Dash.  Google's Picasa is a good example of this.  In any event, if you right mouse click on the 'Applications' icon in the launcher on the left side of the screen, you will see a Gnome-like menu.

[image]

Now, it seems to me if the Gnome-like menu displayed were configured to show Wine applications, you would have the ability to immediately access those applications.  I suspect that this work would need to take place in `/etc/xdg/menus`.

I don't know that this will help, but it is something I have been thinking about as of late.

Answer (score 0):

You can create also Quicklist launcher, something like this

[Wine programs Quicklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/52352#52352)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that the Wine .desktop Files are not marked as executable. You need to goto `~/.local/share/applications/` and execute `chmod -R +x *` which will mark all Files within this directory as executable (what the should be).

Comment: Note: Wine automatically creates .desktop File. Unity can't see them as they are net marked as executable.

Answer (score 0):

This classic menu application indicator is supposed to include Wine applications:
https://askubuntu.com/a/46811/18665