# Can Wine software use Unity Application Menu?

Tags: unity, wine, appmenu

Wine applications which I used show menu under window top border. Is there any way to use global application menu in Wine applications? Will this function be available in next releases of Wine/appmenu possibly?

Comment: I have a feeling what you need is right here :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/47067/can-i-add-wine-application-category-list-to-unity-dash Seems to explain exactly what you're trying to do...hope this helps!

Comment: No, I`m talking about global menu on top of the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll note that Mark Shuttleworth asked me this exact question about a year ago when Unity was first being shared with us.

Wine cannot use the global menu, and probably won't ever.  The reason is that Unity's global menu requires fancy rewriting of each windowing toolkit (GTK, for instance) -- this is why some applications like LibreOffice don't actually yet use the global menu: they were written with toolkits that Unity doesn't yet support.

To make the global menu work in Wine would require an even more invasive rewrite of Wine itself - Wine isn't just implementing the Windows graphical toolkits, but must also act as a window manager.  Windows applications have almost no qualms about doing very strange things, and likely many applications would break in bizarre ways if their menus were moved or worked even slightly differently.