# How can I fully maximize wine applications?

Tags: wine, maximized, menu-bar

In wine, my maximized applications retain the bar at top with title and minimize/maximize buttons. This duplicates the Ubuntu global menu and costs me precious screen space on my laptop. I would like to get rid of this bar in wine either by integrating the two bars or omitting the wine bar. Does anyone know how to do this?

I am aware of the askubuntu question at end, which is related, but slightly different. The answer there seems to indicate that it is impossible for application menus in wine to use the global menu bar because of the variety and complexity of menus. To clarify, I don't need to integrate the application menus, I just want to remove the redundant bar.

[screenshot](http://ubuntuone.com/6dao1Y1EfOlfjosEtKs8Zu)

[Can Wine software use Unity Application Menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52841/can-wine-software-use-unity-application-menu/55186#55186)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you install CompizConfig Settings Manager, you can open the settings for the "Window Decoration" plugin and set "Decoration Windows" to `!(class=Wine & state=maxhorz)`

In detail, the Decoration Windows setting determines which windows *do* have decorations (the default is "any"). The "class=Wine" attribute is set by wine on the windows it opens, and "state=maxhorz" matches any window that is horizontally maximized.  The exclamation point reverses the entire expression (e.g. windows have decorations if they're *not* maximized wine windows).

If you want to make sure that your setting catches any app that behaves this way and not just wine, you can simplify the decoration windows setting to just `!state=maxhorz`

Comment: You are a brilliant man, sir. Works perfectly for me!

Comment: I can only agree with Sam, this is brilliant. And yet another reason why Compiz rules.