# jetbrains editors

Tags: 14.04, menu, intellij

The main menu of Intellij IDEA, where the file and other options are, does not appear in the Ubuntu black bar at the top of the screen. All of my other aplications have main menues that appear there so I am curious why jetbrains products are different for me.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Wine software use Unity Application Menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/52841/can-wine-software-use-unity-application-menu); it's about Wine software not IntelliJ but the reason comes down to the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

It because Java GUI projects as Swing or AWT don't support Unity natively.

But you can easily fix it using [java-swing-ayatana](https://code.google.com/p/java-swing-ayatana/) project. Follow by **[this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/global-menu-android-studio-netbeans-intellij-idea/)** guide to enable global menu.