# Stacks for Unity Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, quicklists

I'm looking forward to emulate the behavior of OS X Dock Stacks so that I can have, for instance, one stack for browsers and another one for IDES.
People at ask ubuntu are doing a lot of cleaver stuff with custom Launchers and Quicklists (see [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity)).
So has anyone figured out how to have stacks in Unity? Anything fancier than a static Quicklist over a dummy folder icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a try to [Cairo Dock](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CairoDock), whose interface is easy to set up as you wish and its gadgets includes stacking with several fancy features.

## Screenshot from my Desktop:

[image]

## More screenshots from the net:

### Parabolic style sub-dock:

[image]

### Dock over dock style

[image]

### Slide style sub-dock

[image]

### Rainbow style sub-dock

[image]

Good luck!

Sorry, I forgot to mention the Panel Mode, which is cool, an illustration is placed here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Drawers](http://launchpad.net/drawers).

You can put just about anything in a drawer by drag and drop. You can even nest drawers inside one another. See below for a screenshot. It's been submitted to the software center but is awaiting review.

In the meantime, to install drawers run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install drawers
```

Then create your first drawer by opening the dash and typing Drawers.

Sources : https://askubuntu.com/a/168563/82505 and the [developers of drawer](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/drawers-12076-released-persistent-mode-and-configuration-panel).