# Stack docklet like docky in Ubuntu 12.04 Unity

Tags: unity, dock

I remember that Ubuntu with GNOME 2.3 had an awesome app called docky.

I much prefer the Unity desktop, so I'm just asking if there's any way to make a stack docklet like this in this screenshot.

[image: directories stacked like a stem]

Comment: Related - http://askubuntu.com/questions/151650/tweak-that-allows-osx-like-stacks-in-unity-launcher?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Cairo Dock 3.0 in your system. It works fine and is comfortable to use.

You can install it using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```

It maintains the naturalism of Unity along with the convenience of a proper dock.

Comment: Will, thanks every one. but I don't like to use multiple docks! Unity's bar is just like a dock and I can't use more than this bar!
if there's any plugin or something for unity I'll appreciate this. 
thanks

Comment: No Unity's Launcher is a Launcher nothing more nothing less, and no there's no plug ins nor anything near that for Unity at the moment. This are your only options for stacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `avant-window-navigator`. It has a stack plugin in the applet window.
The terminal command is:

```
sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator
```

Here is [a good tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1714111) about using avant-window-navigator.

Here is a picture of stack applet

[image]

After you added the applet, right click on the stack applet icon, and select "Preferences". In the "Stack layout" tab, select `curged-gui` option.

[image]

For adding anything on the stack, Press `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT` after selecting the item and drag and drop it in the stack.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cairo-Dock's Stack applet lets you stack files, folders and URL.
Simply drop anything inside the dock and it will be automatically added to the Stack