# How to list folders horizontally , like iOS, in Unity launch bar

Tags: unity, launcher, directory

It's possible to create a folders like iOS in unity launch bar?

I mean, you can click on an icon, and then icons will appear horizontal with a few icons.

This could save space on unity launch bar. And I would like to know if these space saving solutions are available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stacks for Unity Launcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48615/stacks-for-unity-launcher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a little app that is very similar to folders on a Mac dock called Drawers: http://launchpad.net/drawers

You can put just about anything in a drawer by drag and drop. You can even nest drawers inside one another. See below for a screenshot.

To install, run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install drawers
```

Then create your first drawer by opening the dash and typing Drawers.

[image: Screenshot of Drawers]

Comment: Hi, your app looks fantastic! I've installed your app but when I create drawers icon (drag from ~/.local/share/application to unity launch bar) and click it, it's only blink. It doesn't work for me, drag and drop other applications, folders etc. I've Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, Unity 5.14. Could you help me?

Comment: Yes... There was a bug in the latest release that caused empty drawers not to open.  The fix has been committed and will be released soon.  In the meantime, just drag and drop a file onto the launcher icon to place an item in the drawer.  It should open then.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a "quick list". https://askubuntu.com/a/35526/47291

It is not *exactly* like OSX or iOS but it will enable you to list folders with one icon on the launcher.