# Searching for a Ubuntu icon theme

Tags: unity, icons, icon-themes

I'm searching for the name (and eventually links) of an icon theme.

Here are two screenshots found on [another askubuntu page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48615/stacks-for-unity-launcher):

[Icon theme image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5L1N.png)

[Icon theme image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A01n6.png)

Can you please give me the name of that icon theme, and the links if you have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be the Neon icon pack by FRUiT:

[image]

This is the page I found for it:

https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Neon+Icon+theme+by+FRUiT?content=111035&PHPSESSID=6

It's quite an old icon pack, and I don't know how well it's going to work on a modern Ubuntu installation.

The linked site there seems to have been taken over by a scam site, but the creator of the theme has posted a link to a download in the comments:

http://ulozto.net/xSNavA51/neon-icons-by-fruit-0-2-tar-gz

Unfortunately, that link seems to be dead. However, after searching aroud a bit, I think I found the new location of that download service:

https://uloz.to/!Hm2rnzTA/neon-icons-by-fruit-0-2-tar-gz

I am currently downloading the pack and will host it on MEGA so as to provide a better, more permanent, link.

---

UPDATE: looks like there's actually a valid link under the "Files" tab:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/9psa8lz4f4wq949/neon-icons-by-FRUiT.tar.gz

---

(icon pack found using Google image search)

Comment: Thank you very much !!!!! It's exactly what I was searching for !!!! And thank you very much for the updated links, really great answer !!!! 

I downloaded the icon theme, extracted it, copied it to /usr/share/icons and then selected it with Unity Tweak Tool and it works great !!!! 

I've done +1 to your answer but I don't know if it was registered, I will try later again. And again, thank you !