# Why don't my quicklists appear when I use Unity 2D?

Tags: 11.04, unity-2d, quicklists

For reference, I'm currently using Ubuntu 11.04 running on an Asus EeePC 1001HA, running Unity-2D.

I've been trying to add Quicklists into my Unity Launcher, following instructions from this [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity). So what I do is I:

- Copy the requested `*.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/`.
- Make my edits.
- Logout and login again to reflect the new changes.

This doesn't work -- the quicklists doesn't appear when I right-click them.

What I do next is...

- Open Nautilus, and find the `*.desktop` file.
- Right-click the Launcher icon I want to replace, and select "Remove From Launcher".
- Drag the `*.desktop` files I want to use on launcher directly.

The icon appears, but the quicklist doesn't, when I right-click the icon. This persists even after restarts.

As an example, here's my `google-chrome.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Google Chrome
# Only KDE 4 seems to use GenericName, so we reuse the KDE strings.
# From Ubuntu's language-pack-kde-XX-base packages, version 9.04-20090413.
GenericName=Web Browser
# Not translated in KDE, from Epiphany 2.26.1-0ubuntu1.
GenericName[fil]=Web Browser
# Gnome and KDE 3 uses Comment.
Comment=Access the Internet
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity
Terminal=false
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;Incognito;

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=google-chrome
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Incognito Shortcut Group]
Name=New incognito window
Exec=google-chrome --incognito
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

I definitely know that dragging the `*.desktop` file to the Launcher works -- if I change the `exec` directive to include `--incognito`, the browser *does* launch in incognito mode.

But for some strange reason the quicklist doesn't appear. Is this there an issue with how my Unity-2D is set up, or aren't quicklists supported by Unity-2D?

Comment: I deleted my original reply to your question because I have done some reading about Custom Quicklists and found nothing to aid you in finding a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this fix on 11.04 by using the [daily unity-2d updates ppa](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas/76) and then running

```
unity --replace
```

from an alt-F2 prompt.

Comment: Lovely. This method works!

Answer (score 5):

There is a [bug #669923](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/669923) on quicklist support in Unity-2D that was fixed in release [unity-2d 3.8.6](https://launchpad.net/unity-2d/+milestone/3.8.6). You may need to update your Unity-2D package.

Comment: Hmm. The latest version seems to be unity-2d 3.8.41. When will I be able to update to 3.8.6? Can I already do that?

Comment: It's at 3.8.8 for Oneiric 11.10. - if it will not be upgraded in 11.04 you may have to wait for 11.10 or compile (and test) yourself Unity 2D still is in development.

Comment: Bummer. Well, the functionality isn't critical at this point, so I think I can live with waiting a little. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @T-Boy: 11.10 is going to be awesome!