# Is it possible to restart only the dash and panel with launchers without restarting unity?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, quicklists

I know there is `unity-panel-service', which is used for restarting the panel. But it is possible restart the "Dash/Launchers" section without restarting the whole unity plugin?

I have used  for my [gftp Quicklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/52326#52326), the way with `unity --replace &`, but this is not the best way. If you have Quicklist with possibility to generate menu items dynamically, it would be nice to have possibility restart only the whole Launcher.

I have try also,to get the favorites list with gsettings , change it and roll it back, but without awaited result.

For now only the `unity --replace` is the working solution or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

However, if you made a script use libunity you can have a real [dynamic quicklist](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Dynamic_Quicklist_entries) instead of generating a new static one on demand. Check out the [Opera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/41228#41228) one for an example.

Comment: Thanks, for the help, the libunity is perfect solution for my future quicklist

Answer (score 3):

Try a `killall -SIGHUP unity-2d-shell` as normal/logged in user.

This closes the launcher icon bar and opens it again.

Answer (score 1):

This command worked for me:

```
DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace&
```

The DISPLAY=:0 is needed only if calling from another shell (for example, when using ctrl-F1 terminal).