# get a launcher on the unity launcher that shows all connected drives/devices in a quicklist

Tags: unity, scripts, quicklists

I have had the thought of adding a single icon/launcher to my unity launcher. just a single icon that when clicked or right click it shows the mounted drives in a quicklist and allows me to open the drive/device {even if clicking does nothing and the only way to get the quickest or menu is to right click the the icon would be super} I was thinking maybe creating a .desktop file and use a script to do the dirty work would be a way to achieve this. It does not have to be anything fancy I'd just like to try and get something that will do the job. I'm thinking just a single icon on the launcher that does nothing when clicked but right clicking it shows a quicklist of all mounted drives would be the easiest way?.
I am only new to ubuntu and linux and I would like to ask if someone would be kind enough to please try their best to help and make this idea work? as I'm sure there has to be a way it can be done, as I said before it don't have to be fancy at all, if it's crude but works that is fine by me.

thank you for your time

Ray.

Comment: This is the closest a user got: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/43150#43150 (scripts reads your bookmarks and adds them to home-quicklist).

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for your input mate!. would you be able to guide me through how to alter that script to work with usb drives at all please?

Comment: It's not what you are looking for, but maybe these indicator-apps might interest you: **USB-safe-removal** http://askubuntu.com/a/37989/3962 and **Places Indicator** http://askubuntu.com/a/42432/3962

Answer (score 1):

While this would be a useful tool at present this functionality is not available in Unity.

As such this is better addressed as a feature request and I would look at the [Unity Get Involved](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/) page for ideas on how best to help and put your idea forward.

You can also join the [Ayatana mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~unity-design) and contribute ideas etc.

Another good site is [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) which is a popular source for feature requests.