# What are the options for a very simple launcher?

Tags: software-recommendation, launcher

I'm not overly impressed with the new Unity launcher following my upgrade to 11.04. Ubuntu 10.04 with Gnome wasn't too bad once you'd sorted out all your `*.desktop` files and I'd been running with this for quite a while, but the number of problems I (and others) seem to be having with Unity is considerable.

And, while *I* may be happy spending the next few weeks trying to nut things out, my major client base (i.e., the wife) is none too happy.

What are the options for a very simple launcher, with the following specs?

- Small icon which will bring up a text menu. Perhaps in the top area near the power button and network indicator and so forth.
- This icon should be always on top so I can get to it regardless of what's on the screen.
- This icon should be on every workspace so that I can start programs from anywhere.
- A simple text configuration file that I can edit with vi, containing just the menu name and the command to run.
- The menu should come up fast. I don't want to wait two seconds while it reads the configuration file just on the off chance I've changed something (it changes very rarely and, when it does, I'll restart it myself).

I don't really want to go back to classic Gnome since I *will* eventually figure out Unity, so I don't consider that an option. I'm hoping there's a simple solution to this problem that will suffice until my Unity-fu is stronger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally found a way to do it that requires zero extra configuration.

The trick is to run `gnome-panel` itself, which is the old task bar application pre-Unity.

First of all, run the `System Setting` program from your shutdown icon (the power switch in the top right corner of the screen). From there, select `Startup Applications`.

Add a  new application with the name `GnomePanel` and the command `gnome-panel`. This will run the old panel on startup.

Then reboot and voila! All your old settings are there, still controlled by the old methods.

I also disabled all the key bindings for Unity except for the `Super` key itself since `gnome-panel` uses some of these, and set the launcher hide policy to `Auto-hide`.

These last few steps are done in `ccsm` under `Desktop`, `Ubuntu Unity plug-in`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want. You say you don't want to replace Unity, but you want to add a menu that can be easily edited with a text editor and is fast to use? You can do that with any or all of the icons on the launcher. I think that's the best suggestion. There are lots of readily available menus of that kind which you can use as a template to add your own. It's just a four easy lines, containing a name, a command and, etc. Have a look at these:

[What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity)

Comment: I don't want to replace Unity since that's the way Ubuntu's going. But I want something I can use _now._ Trying to sort out whether Unity starts a new app or activates a current one, or wondering why multiple Nautilus windows only have one icon in the launcher, or figuring out how to get multiple commands on a single icon is no doubt doable, but I want something I can use with almost no learning curve - I don't want to muck about with editing configs and restarting Unity a hundred times to test them. That can come later when I'm not so pressed for time.