# Custom unity launcher for audacity

Tags: unity, launcher, menu, audacity

I use audacity a lot so would like a  custom launcher menu for audacity in unity.

Similar to this [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity) but specific to audacity

Menu may include something like 'new file' with out obtained message ' a session audacity is currently open ... ' etc

PS : sorry for my english ... --

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple lanucher for Audacity:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Audacity
Comment=Musical Editor
Exec=audacity
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=audacity
StartupNotify=true
```