# Customization for quicklists of Unity is reverted after reboot

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity) to modify my quicklists of Unity. For examples in order to add an "Root Terminal" item I modified my `gnome-terminal.desktop` as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
Comment=Use the command line
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
X-GNOME-DocPath=gnome-terminal/index.html
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-terminal
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=BugBuddyBugs
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.32.1
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-terminal

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Root;
[Root Shortcut Group]
Name=Root Terminal
Exec=gksudo gnome-terminal
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

And then I dragged it to the launcher. It worked fine before rebooting. But after the system is restarted, the Terminal button launcher is reverted (No `Root Terminal` after right click), despite of the desktop file has been modified.

So what steps do I miss? Thanks for those who gives hints.

Comment: Did you copy the `.desktop` file over to `~/.local/share/applications` before editing? Is it still there after the reboot? Did you check `~./.xsession-errors` for errors related to this?

Comment: Oh, I edited the file in place (/usr/share/applications). It seems I have some misunderstanding about the mechanism.

Comment: ah time for an answer >:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to copy the `.desktop` file over to `~/.local/share/applications` and to edit that version. `~/.local/share/applications` overrules the `.desktop` from `/usr/share/applications`.

The ones in `/usr/share/applications` get recreated probably to prevent malformed desktop files to crash Unity: in case of a crash it can fallback to the unchanged version.

Comment: Thank you @Rinzwind, it works great but I have another question. If I copy the file to ~/.local/share/applications, a new item will be created on the launcher. However when I open something and select "Keep in Launcher", the .desktop file does not appear in the folder. So where this information is stored?