# Location of .desktop file of "Application lens" of Unity

Tags: 11.04, unity, lenses, quicklists

I would like to modify QUICKLIST of Unity "Application lens" but I haven't managed to find .desktop file which I could modify.

Could you please help me?

Screenshot of quicklist of Unity application len:

[image]

---

- The quicklist was activated with RIGHT-CLICK on the icon
- Known quicklist modifications:
  [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity)
- /usr/share/unity/places/applications.place file found but I haven't managed to edit it in a manner that would lead to quicklist modification

---

As new items in quicklist of launchers were appended here: [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity), I wanted to append new items in quicklist of applications lens. Just other commands related with applications management to be present in this quicklist. (I want to have as less icons on unity bar as possible). But maybe I will really have to create separate launcher for the commands.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot manipulate that list. Maybe you can create a new launcher with shortcuts to those lens filters?

Answer (score 1):

This quicklist is coded into Unity, and it is not editable without changing the code of Unity itself.

Answer (score 1):

The quicklist is coded into a separate application: unity-lens-applications. It is likely populated dynamically, over dbus, by the applications lens itself. In short, there is no easy way to edit it. If you happen to know some programming and you're really set on it, you could grab the source from [the project on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-applications) and make a change there.

That said, perhaps what you want is something that should be happening in the first place. What are you looking to change?