# Where to store unzipped application files

Tags: unity, system-installation, unity-dash

I have used apt-get a lot to install programs, but I just recently wanted to use Abricotine markdown editor. The way it says to install it is by downloading and extracting a zip file. I do that, and the program has an executable file there along with some other folders and stuff.

I'm new to Linux in general, so could someone tell me where I should move these files and folders? I tried using the terminal to move the whole unzipped directory to /usr/shares/, but then when I search the computer (I'm on Ubuntu 16.10) it doesn't show up.

Where should these files go?

Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1148/what-is-the-best-place-to-install-user-apps is this your question?

Comment: I think so, but the answers didn't do it for me... I am pretty new to Linux so many I'm not explaining well enough. All I did was go to the GitHub program's repo, download the archive file, and extract it. The program is in there and it works. How can I get it to show up in Unity's search now? I moved to to /opt and it still doesn't show up. Does Ubuntu just have to reindex my programs or something?

Comment: Do any files show up when you search?

Comment: Yes, they all do, except for Abricotine.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67373/search-for-applications-not-in-path-from-unity-dash ?

Comment: That sounds more like what I need. Do I really have to do this every time I download an external program just to be able to search for it through? He linked here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available/35523#35523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity Dash uses locate, so to reindex a program in /opt/ try

```
sudo updatedb -U /opt/
```

To get only the program to show up, with a nice icon and everything, you'll have to [create a .desktop file.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67373/search-for-applications-not-in-path-from-unity-dash) Also see [adding program to launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224004/how-to-add-programs-to-the-launcher).

Comment: Thanks, that works! The only (smaller) issue is that when it DOES find it in search, it displays the folder its in, along with the other files and folders it has as well, plus the actual program. Also, the program icon isn't displaying and showing as an icon with a lot of 1s and 0s.

Comment: @Andrew I have updated my answer. If you found it helpful, I would appreciate it if you marked it as accepted.