# How to add lenses to the launcher?

Tags: unity, 11.10, launcher, lenses

Can someone tell me how to add the More Apps and Find Files button to the Ubuntu 11.10 Launch bar?  They were both in the Dash Home and the Launch bar in version 11.04.  Now it's not in the 11.10 by default.

If they were in the Launcher they would be easier to use.  It'd also save clicks and mouse movement.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design you're supposed to be able to do this, but right now you can't. It's just not implemented yet:

- https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/unity-design/+bug/878318

Comment: Thanks, Jorege Castro.  You might have been typing while I was updating my message.  I tried that ( https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/unity-design/+bug/878318 ).  You can drag applications to the Launcher, but you can't drag the More Apps and More Files to the Launcher.

Comment: @L.D.James yeah it's supposed to be able to, it's just not written yet, maybe for 12.04!

Comment: Thanks again Jorge.  I was typing my response when I pressed ENTER and couldn't edit any more because of slow typing (more than 5 minutes).

I hoped to resolve this issue ( http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11349491&postcount=5 ) plus a number of others with other users who are spending lots of productive time moving the mouse around the screens and clicking.  If we can find a way to get the "More Apps" and "More Files" on the Launcher, any program or vile will be two clicks away.

Comment: A quick workaround would be to use super-a and super-f to go right to those lenses.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response, Jorge.  Can you imagine of a way to call up that procedure or app from a script or commandline?  I can probably create a custom file (moreapps.desktop) and add that to the Launcher.

I just create a test example that brings up Emacs and was able to bring that to the Launcher.

Thanks in advance for input on this, or if I'm not clear with this question.

Comment: Yeah you can always just make a custom launcher, though you'd have to do that by hand: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity

Comment: Is there a program or script that can be run from the terminal that will bring up the "More Apps" or "Find Files" window?