# Are there Unity-like quicklists for GNOME?

Tags: gnome, quicklists

Is there a way to have [Quicklists like in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity) but then in the Gnome 3 dash?

Mainly I would like to be able to open a specific directory in Nautilus directly, [like this quicklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/35526#35526), and be able to open certain commands in the Terminal directly, [like this quicklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/39532#39532).

Is there Quicklists in Gnome or is there some other way of achieving this quick way to enter directories / commands?

Answer (score 4):

They [are planned](https://live.gnome.org/Design/Whiteboards/Jumplists) for the future, called "Jump Lists" in GNOME 3 lingo, but are currently only implemented as [an extension installable at extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/33/jump-lists/). It should be noted that "Application menus" currently serve a similar role.

Action lists have been added to [the FreeDesktop.org app launcher specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s08.html). In theory, all compliant desktop environments may make use of quicklists.

[image: Screenshot of jump lists in Activities overlay]

Answer (score 3):

I wrote little extension for implemetation of quicklist: [extensions.gnome.org/extension/322/quicklists/](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/322/quicklists/). At now it is very primitive, and it may not work correctly with Unity specific .desktop files. There can be (there are) some bugs, so please don't judge badly this extension at start - this is only first not perfect version. I uses Ubuntu12.04, so extension is available for Shell 3.4.1.

Comment: nice work Damian, I just installed you extension and it looks pretty good (code quality is not too bad either :))

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, from what I understand, Gnome 3 doesn't support the necessary tags in their .desktop files yet.  Until Gnome codes together some support or someone writes an extension for this, there isn't really a way to get quick-lists in Gnome Shell at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 6months later... but here is your answer as to how to do it-

Its just another extention from the gnome extentions..

Visit and install the extention from [Here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/322/quicklists/)

For more details,visit [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/how-to-use-unity-quicklists-in-gnome-shell) page.

Hope it helps..!! ;)