# How to add quicklist to favourite applications in GNOME Shell

Tags: gnome, quicklists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there Unity-like quicklists for GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79899/are-there-unity-like-quicklists-for-gnome)

I had a lot of quicklists configured in my Unity. But I do not know how to add quicklist to an application in GNOME shell.

[image: Screenshot]

For example, I need an **"Enter Private Browsing"** option under Firefox and **"Enter Incognito Mode"** shortcut under Chromium Browser.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way of doing so. Gnome 3 doesn't yet support the X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts tag in .desktop files (though I'm planning to write a gnome-shell-extension over the weekend to rectify this). I'll update this answer with the relevant link on Monday. You'll have your quicklist functionality then.

Although I must say it's a feature which should already have been released to the community by canonical, since it's such a simple extension. I don't like unity and I feel they're going down a bad road. It won't be long before I'm switching to arch/mint if they continue this embrace-extend-extinguish approach to linux development.

Comment: I will wait for your extension.

Comment: Did this extension become a reality?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'd been planning it for a while when I posted this answer, but extensions can't do IO, so I would have needed to fork gnome-shell to get it working.

I submitted a couple of patches to GnomeApplication to get this working for 3.4, but the relevant feature has been pushed back to 3.6, so at the moment it looks like it's not going to happen.
http://live.gnome.org/ThreePointThree/Features/ApplicationMenu