# Can I put more applications in a Unity icon?

Tags: unity, launcher

Is it possible to 'enclose' more than one application in a single Unity icon/button?
In order to keep under control the number of buttons on launcher, it will be very useful to me to store some applications of the same type (e.g. small accessory applications like take screenshot or web application etc. ) in a single button as that is possible with the xfce panel...

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm Ubuntu **11.10** and **Unity** (3D), vs. some other variant.

Comment: yes Ubuntu Oneiric & Unity 3D

Answer (score 19):

## Overview

This answer gives two potential answers - *Drawers* and *Quicklists*

## Drawers

*Drawers* is available via a PPA for 12.04:

[image]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install drawers
```

Launch Drawers from Dash.  For you drawer, drag and drop the created icon from `~/.local/share/applications`.

Launch your drawer - then you can drag and drop your favourite applications from the Dash onto the drawer.

## Graphical Quicklists

The default unity method to launch multiple options is through the use of quicklists - right-click a launcher icon to show a menu of options for that launcher icon.

[image]

The creation of quicklist using a graphical method for 12.04 is available using *MyUnity*

### [myunity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/myunity) [image: Install myunity]

[image]

This option allows you to create quicklists - quicklists are a submenu that are displayed when you right-click a launcher icon.

The creation of quicklist using a graphical method for 11.04 is *work-in-progress* - for example - the *Unity Launcher Editor*

[image]

This works in Natty (ubuntu 11.04) - but due to the python version change, does not work (as at the time of writing this) in oneiric (ubuntu 11.10)

**to install**

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt-get install bzr
bzr branch lp:unity-launcher-editor
```

**to run**

```
cd ~/Downloads/unity-launcher-editor
./ule
```

## Manual creation of quicklists

Fortunately, it is simple to create quicklists manually as well. A quicklist is a *.desktop* file containing at the minimum the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=adressbook
Name=Sample Menu
Exec=example_application1

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=example_app2;

[example_apps Shortcut Group]
Name=Name of Application 2
Exec=example_application2
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Let's break this down to the areas you should change (working from top to bottom of the example).

- `Icon=`: this is the graphical picture file found in `/usr/share/icons`
- `Name=`: this is the tooltip you see when you hover over the launcher icon
- `Exec=`: this is the default executable run when you left click the launcher icon
- `X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=`: this is a semi-colon separated list of groups.

Each group is a quick-list menu option under the entry `[group_name Shortcut Group]`

- `example_apps` this is the name of the group in the `X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts` field
- `Name=`: this is the quicklist menu text
- `Exec=`: this is the executable run when choosing the quicklist entry

*.desktop* files should exist in the local folder `~/.local/share/applications`

If it doesn't already exist create this folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
```

Create a file in the folder - for example *myquicklist.desktop* and drag-and-drop this file from Nautilus into the Unity Launcher.

## mimic XFCE launcher

The default XFCE action when clicking on the launcher button is to run an executable.  For our launcher you could default to the calculator

```
Name=My Quicklist
Exec=gcalctool
```

The other action possible in the XFCE launcher is to just display the list of launcher items.  Unfortunately in Unity you cannot do this - it must be a right-click.

The default `Exec=` must run something - for example you could use this to display a quick pop-up dialog reminding you to right click:

```
Name=My Quicklist
Exec=zenity --title="action" --info --text="Right-Click for quicklist" --height=50 --width=275 --timeout=2
```

## Example

You gave the following examples that you wanted:

- Screenshot: `Exec=gnome-screenshot -i`
- Dictionary: `Exec=xfce4-dict`
- Calculator: `Exec=gcalctool`

[image]

Thus your example *.desktop* file would look like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=addressbook
Name=My Quicklist
Exec=zenity --title="action" --info --text="Right-Click for quicklist" --height=50 --width=275 --timeout=2

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=screenshot;dictionary;calculator

[screenshot Shortcut Group]
Name=Gnome Screenshot
Exec=gnome-screenshot -i
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[dictionary Shortcut Group]
Name=XFCE Dictionary
Exec=xfce4-dict
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[calculator Shortcut Group]
Name=Gnome Calculator
Exec=gcalctool
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - package `drawers` not found after adding given repository. This is $3 at Software Center.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use Launcher quicklists to add applications to the right click menu of a launcher icon. Look at this question:

- [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity)

Specifically the [libreoffice example](https://askubuntu.com/q/36375/235) can be modified to just run whatever applications you want under the same icon.

Comment: Thanx Jorge, but in my Ubuntu Oneiric there is not any *.desktop file in /usr/share/applications/ moreover I can't follow the LibreOffice example because it has a starting centre while I'd like to create a new botton in launcher (with a chosen icon) which contains some useful 'small' applications (Screenshot, Dictionary, Calculator, Force quit ecc.)... Is that possible?

Comment: If you're looking at that folder with Nautilus, the names displayed are different than the file names for .desktop files. On the CLI the ls command will show the real file names which you need to edit those files.

Answer (score 5):

**For Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric) and Unity (3D)**

Example: "*Ubuntu Toolbox*" multi-purpose icon

Description: *A single 'toolbox' icon, replacing multiple Unity launcher icons, for: **Systems Settings** (default), **Ubuntu Tweak**, **Ubuntu Software Center**, and **Software Updates**.*

[image]

Comments: *I did make some compromises on icons (not custom), file naming, and the default item.  Other alternatives might clash or could be confused with existing items.* (be warned)

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/applications  (if required)

gedit ~/.local/share/applications/toolbox.desktop &
```

Note: *The ampersand '&' releases the command line immediately.*

My custom '**toolbox.desktop**' file: (can be easily edited)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu Toolbox
Comment=System Settings
Exec=gnome-control-center --overview
Icon=redhat-tools
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-control-center
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=shell
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.2.1
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-control-center-2.0

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=UbuntuTweak;SoftwareCenter;SoftwareUpdates;

[UbuntuTweak Shortcut Group]
Name=Ubuntu Tweak
Exec=ubuntu-tweak
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[SoftwareCenter Shortcut Group]
Name=Ubuntu Software Center
Exec=software-center
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[SoftwareUpdates Shortcut Group]  
Name=Update Manager  
Exec=update-manager -c  
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Answer (score 5):

**Drawers** are a perfect way to group applications in the Unity Laucher.

As of now, it is not available in the repos but you can still install it from the ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install drawers
```

Some screenshots to show the use of drawers

[image]

[image]

Once you create a new drawer, you can drag & drop applications from the Dash.

You can even store files and folders in your drawer, providing a way of quickly accesing commonly used files.

[image]

**Sources:**
http://maketecheasier.com/group-apps-together-in-unity-launcher/2012/08/10
http://www.iloveubuntu.net/how-easily-group-items-featuring-their-own-mini-dash-unity-launcher-drawers

Comment: Just released a new version today (12/10/12) with new configuration options and bug fixes... Hope you like it!

Comment: drag&drop does not work for me :( ... What could be the problem? I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

I think both david6 & fossfreedom's answers are quite good, this is just to show you a variation of the same.

In this case it's a 'Utility' icon I have for various actions, it uses standard app's, some shell scripts & commands. Because I use synaptic the most i've set the left click on the icon to run synaptic, everything else is off of the right click quicklists.

One additional point of interest - in custom .desktops with quicklists the 'X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=' line determines what is shown in the quicklist & the order shown.

Ex. - You could have 10 [whatever Shortcut Group] entries but only show some of them by what's in the 'X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=' line

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=synaptic-pkexec
Name=Utilities
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/categories/48/applications-other.svg
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=UpdateManager;CompizConfig;Htop;GetUpdates;NautilusActions;DconfEditor;GconfEditor;ForceQuit;ScreenShot;SeachFiles;Gksu;

[UpdateManager Shortcut Group]
Name=Update Manager
Exec=/usr/bin/update-manager
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Htop Shortcut Group]
Name=Htop
Exec=htop1
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[GetUpdates Shortcut Group]
Name=Update Sources
Exec=update1
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[NautilusActions Shortcut Group]
Name=Nautilus Actions
Exec=nautilus-actions-config-tool
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[CompizConfig Shortcut Group]
Name=Compiz Settings
Exec=ccsm
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[GconfEditor Shortcut Group]
Name=Gconf Editor
Exec=gconf-editor
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[ForceQuit Shortcut Group]
Name=Force Quit
Exec=xkill
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[ScreenShot Shortcut Group]
Name=Screen Shots
Exec=gnome-screenshot --interactive
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[SeachFiles Shortcut Group]
Name=Search For Files
Exec=gnome-search-tool
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[DconfEditor Shortcut Group]
Name=Dconf Editor
Exec=dconf-editor
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Gksu Shortcut Group]
Name=Root Nautilus
Exec=gksudo nautilus
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

To give Ex. of small scripts, Exec=htop1 is just a file named htop1 in a bin in my $PATH (~/bin

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --command  htop
```

Exec=update1 is one named update1

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --command "sudo apt-get update"
```

In a .desktop with extensive quicklists if one wanted to save space on the X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts= line you could name your shortcut groups in a simpler fashion, using something like Scg1;Scg2;Scg3; ect, so

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Scg1;Scg2;Scg3; ect.

As an example taking my first entry

```
[Scg1 Shortcut Group]
Name=Update Manager
Exec=/usr/bin/update-manager
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Lots of things & variations of how you can do with your launcher icons, quicklists, ect.,

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is not an answer to your question, but i think it is the same as launcher do(or simply `alternatives`).
1) try [Gnome-Pie](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/gnome-pie-03-released-with-mouse.html) (an application launcher with some really cool effects)
[image: Gnome-Pie]

---

2) Using docks, such as [Glx-Dock/Cairo-Dock](http://glx-dock.org/)(such as dock in mac) and docky(they are in the software-center).

[image: Cairo-Dock]

---

3) Using shortcuts to open programs(write keyboard in the dash and open it >> go to shortcuts tap >> go to custom shortcuts >> press the + button >> write the program you want to open with the shortcut >> apply >> assign a shortcut to it)

[image: shortcuts]

Answer (score 1):

Check out a new application: Drawers
[image]
http://www.iloveubuntu.net/how-easily-group-items-featuring-their-own-mini-dash-unity-launcher-drawers

http://www.iloveubuntu.net/create-bundles-files-and-folders-unity-launcher-fancy-drawers-ppa-available

you can add the ppa by doing

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install drawers

Just type Drawers into the Dash to get started.  It'll create a drawer launcher in ~/.local/share/applications which you can place on the launcher/dock. Then drag and drop anything you want to it (documents, folders, applications, web-urls).  Left-Clicking opens up a mini-dash with icons for each file, while right-clicking opens up a quicklist.  Right clicking items in the open drawer allows you to edit their name or execution command. Left clicking launches them with their default application.