# One click access to bookmarked files?

Tags: quicklists, bookmarks

On my Windows machine with just one click I can launch favourite or bookmarked files that I use on a daily basis, which is a great time-saver. Is there any way to do this with 11.10 Unity? Ideally I would like to right-click on an icon in the launcher and have a list of files appear that I could then left-click to launch, but I'd be happy for any simple solution.

Please note that I am not referring to recently used files lists - these do not work at all because the bookmarked file will ***always*** drop off the bottom of any recently used file list.

Comment: You should look at this excellent answer - your question reads as if this solution is applicable to you:  http://askubuntu.com/a/43150/14356

Comment: Thanks fossfreedom - that looks great! The only problem is that I cannot see how to bookmark files. It seems that only folders can be bookmarked, or am I wrong about this?

Comment: hmmm - dont have access to my ubuntu at the moment... if you just a static list of files you can create a static quicklist e.g. I've just answered something similar here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/81732/can-i-put-more-applications-in-a-unity-icon

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, only folders can be bookmarked in Ubuntu 11.10 Nautilus. Does anyone know of another way to get individual files into the Unity Launcher as bookmarks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available)

Comment: @dunderhead - please can you add your edit in as an answer and you can accept it.  We can also vote on it as well.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another excellent solution: [Cairo Dock](http://glx-dock.org/)

I am very impressed with this wonderful launcher. It has more features than the Unity launcher, it's much more customisable, and it works wonderfully well out of the box. I don't bother with the Unity launcher any more. I can't recommend this application enough!

Answer (score 1):

In case it's helpful for anyone, there is a solution, thanks to [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) and his excellent answer. I copied the .desktop file of the application to my home directory and edited the line beginning with Exec= to include the file I want to launch. For example, `Exec=appname /home/filename` and then I dragged the edited .desktop file to the Unity Launcher.