# Set up shortcut for different terminal shells

Tags: command-line, scripts

I would like to get some practice using different shells (zsh and ksh, etc...) What is the best way to set it up so I can create a shortcut that will launch a terminal with the desired shell? I'd rather not set up another account or have to chsh each time if possible, but would love to see all my options. As a bonus I would love to see links to resources for learning various different shells.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I put more applications in a Unity icon?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81732/can-i-put-more-applications-in-a-unity-icon)

Comment: @muru I don't really think that is what the OP is looking for, although it is related.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcuts would depend on what terminal you are using. However, most accept the `-e` option to specify what program to run. Therefore, for `zsh` you could do:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e zsh
```

Or, this approach to have a login shell:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e 'zsh -l'
```

You could then add these as *aliases* on your default shell or, if you prefer to have a launcher on Ubuntu's dash, create a file inside `~/.local/share/applications` with the extension `.desktop` and these lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Zsh-Terminal
Comment=Use zsh in the command line
Exec=zsh
Terminal=true
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
```

Make this file executable and drag it to the dash.

Read more about the [difference between login and non login shell.](http://howtolamp.com/articles/difference-between-login-and-non-login-shell/)

Comment: Instead of hardcoding `gnome-terminal`, try `x-terminal-emulator` instead. And you can do: `gnome-terminal -e zsh` instead of using `SHELL`. Better yet, if you're using one launcher per shell, simply specify the shell (`Exec=zsh`) and set `Terminal=true`.

Comment: @muru, my first idea was to use your approach but then using `-e zsh` doesn't make it a login shell. Same thing when just using `Exec=zsh` in the `.desktop` file. I'll edit to add both options and also good point about using `x-terminal-emulator`.

Comment: That depends on whether you have enabled login shells in your terminal emulator (you may have, I haven't, OP may or may not have). Use the `-l` option if that's a problem: `Exec=zsh -l`, or `x-terminal-emulator -e 'zsh -l'`.

Comment: @muru, I did not know that, good call! I'll change it then.