# How can I easily access favorite applications without overpopulating the launcher?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, appmenu

I found only answers to that old dashboard which actually had some kind of settings button.

I'm looking for a way to organise my favourite programs for easy access like the start button in windows. Somewhere to keep programs like Firefox and Excel. I would like to do this without overly cluttering my screen and am open towards privacy conscious external packages but prefer a minimalistic style.

Thank you guys!

Comment: what you propose also crossed my mind.. having more applications occupying one space, like in andrid. Tell me how to do that, please.  
 -----------------------                 
As to my question_: How can I pin programs (I like) to the Dash in 16.10?   -----------------------
or set up an equivalent of that (using other means), something that creates the same effect - having multiple programs in one easily accessible place on the toolbar

Comment: Hi @Thia, will post in a minute.

Comment: You mentioned hidden lists. See this: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/09/launcher-list-indicator-update-ppa-workspaces As for pinning files, it is not supposed to have changed in16.10 which is why i am like Jacob also confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Combining multiple applications into one icon

To combine multiple applications in one icon in the launcher, you can use [QLE Quicklist Editor](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/qle-unity-quicklist-editor-20-released.html)

---

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of the application. The first version was developed when (I believe) 11.04 was just released, but the most recent version still works fine on 16.04. Currently rewriting it, but slowly, ***because*** it still works fine with current Ubuntu versions

---

#### To use the application

1. Install QLE Quicklist Editor:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/qle
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install qle
   ```
2. As an example, I will add a few applications to my pinned `Bluefish` icon:

   [image]

   Open the quicklist editor:

   [image]

   Click on the big + icon, with the small + orange icon inside. In the popup list, choose "Add an application shortcut".
3. In the listbox, select your application and press <kbd>Add</kbd>

   [image]
4. Done. Your applications was added to the icon:

   [image]

Repeat this for every application you want to add to the icon.

#### Note

Make sure your application (in this case Bluefish) is not running when you edit the icon, else you will have to log out/in for the changes to be applied.

---

### 2. Alternatively, run your favorite applications from a menu in the panel

Use the indicator below to make your favorite applications easily accessible
With the setup below, you can have your applications under an icon in the panel:

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3

currpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'update_setting'
        iconpath = currpath+"/icon.png"
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())

    def getscripts(self):
        apps = [l.strip().split("|") for l in open(currpath+"/applist").readlines()\
                if not l == "\n"]
        for l in apps: 
            menuitem = Gtk.MenuItem(l[0])
            menuitem.connect("activate", self.run_script, l[1])
            self.menu.append(menuitem)

    def create_menu(self):
        self.menu = Gtk.Menu()
        self.getscripts()
        # quit
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        sep = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        self.menu.append(sep)
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        self.menu.append(item_quit)
        self.menu.show_all()
        return self.menu

    def run_script(self, widget, script):
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", script])

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

#### The icon

[image]

#### How to use

1. Create a folder to contain the script, the icon and a application list (see further)
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `list_applications.py` in the folder you created.
3. Copy the icon (right-click -> save as), save it as (exactly) `icon.png` in one and the same folder as the script.
4. Now create, again in the very same folder, a file, (exactly) named `applist`(no extension). Now add for each of your applications a line, with the *name* you want to use for the application, and the command to run it. Use the delimiter `|`e.g.:

   [image]
5. Test- run the script with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/list_applications.py
   ```

   If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 &&  python3 /path/to/list_applications.py"
   ```

#### Note

If you add or remove applications to or from the list, the script needs to be restarted.

Comment: Thank you! After a Lot of googling, I decided that Quicklists are the way to go. I used this https://askubuntu.com/questions/81732/can-i-put-more-applications-in-a-unity-icon tutorial from 2011, but I am stuck at the beginning. -------- I can't find ~/.local/share/applications by browsing manually, and I only made 1 file up until now, so I'm also unsure whether to "cat" or "touch" or something else, and whether it needs and extension --- I would like to do this manually because It doesnt seem hard , so can you take a look at that tutorial and tell me whether something is different in 16.10?TNX

Comment: @Thia WOW, that is an old post. Which of the tutorials are you referring to? `~/.local/share/applications` is a hidden directory by default. press Ctrl + H to make it visible. There is an other option however, will look it up...

Comment: I'm reffering to the part in the middle called "Manual creation of quicklists". You basically make a .desktop file in the directory, and fill it with [Desktop Entry],    X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=screenshot;dictionary;calculator,   and  
[screenshot Shortcut Group] ---- and then do something :D If it doesnt work out, I cna use your thing, but I would like to learn more by doing it manually. Check that part please  and tell me if its up to date :D TNX

Comment: @Thia no, it isn't. I might update it, since ` X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=` is totally outdated. Only a few applications use that format. I only know `Inkscape` from the top of my head.

Comment: Hi @Thia added a second option. Run your favorite apps from the panel!

Comment: Wow, It looks great! Nice work. I bet this will help a lot of people in the future. I think i'll do both, though I think I will prefer the quicklist, since the top is so far away :D

Comment: @Thia glad it works :)

Comment: Hey, @Jacob Vlijm I found some obscure italian website, and it looks like the thing we were talking about - manual quicklist. Can you take a peek at the code? Looks legit to me. Most of it is the same as 2011, the difference being a few lines and that Aytana line now being: Actions=Vlc;dvd95;Soundconverter;Asunder;Eastytag;Rhythmbox; -- Sorry for bothering you, I see you are a celebrity around here, I'm just naturally curious about new things :D Tnx! http://www.istitutomajorana.it/forum2/Thread-How-To-Ubuntu-16-04-quicklist-personalizzate

Comment: Hi @Thia see this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24158315/ , an example. `OnlyShowIn=Unity;` is deprecated, but won't hurt. A few fields in your link are unnecessary.

Comment: @Thia haha, you're welcome:)