# Shortcut for iotop in the Unity taskbar?

Tags: 11.10, shortcuts

How can I make a shortcut in the Unity taskbar (the one on the left side of the screen) that starts iotop in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a shortcut and start a terminal with a command *foocommand* like that:

```
gnome-terminal -x foocommand
```

If you e.g. want to run iotop use:

```
gnome-terminal -x iotop
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best solution would be to add gnome-terminal to the launcher and then add a quicklist (right-click menu) to open a iotop terminal, like in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/39532/19779.

Things like this is obviously going to become much easier in the future. Let's hope the future comes quickly! :)