# how can I change the security settings for a website in firefox?

Tags: firefox, quicklists

I have customized my Unity Launcher so that now have access to quicklists for different applications. To do that I followed the script posted here:
[What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)

I added some of my most frequented websites to the firefox launcher. First time I opened one of them firefox asked me to add a security exception, which I did, but doesn't open the website, just a blank page with the following dialogue:

> Welcome to (name of the website)
>   To change this page, upload a new index.html to your private_html folder

I added a security exception of the website in mozilla advanced preferences, which works when opening it through the navigation bar in firefox, but not through the quicklist in Unity.

Comment: Sounds like the website is having problems, not you. Wait a bit and try again, I think?

Comment: I rewrited the script in the firefox.desktop file for the quicklists, so will try to fix it next time I login.

Answer (score 1):

## Please edit your question to include the following details:

1. What website?
2. Do you get that page only from that website? (IE, do any other https addresses break?)
3. Does that website work when you just type the address directly into firefox?
4. Do you get that page only when using the quicklist?
5. Your firefox.desktop

I know you've sort of mentioned some of this in your question, but I'd like you to be explicit and methodical so I can give you the most accurate answer.

## My shoot from the hip answer

It's not you, it's the website. Sounds like someone at whatever.com reset their httpd.conf to factory defaults. But this is pending more information.

Comment: don't think the website's name is relevant, just mentioning that it's kind of a bittorrent tracker to download media files. Never has asked me for a certificate when opening it in firefox, only when i added it to my quicklist in firefox.desktop.

Comment: don't think the website's name is relevant, just mentioning that it's kind of a bittorrent tracker to download media files. Never has asked me for a certificate when opening it in firefox, only when i added it to my quicklist in firefox.desktop. then i get the security exception dialogue, but doesn't get through the quicklists, so removing the script concerning that website in firefox.desktop is the safest thing to do, I guess. Just remember firefox saying that the website in question is using a fake or untrusted certificate. One thing for sure - it's not a terrorist cell.

Comment: It's relevant. Can you reproduce the problem? Can anyone else? Please edit your question with the requested information.