# How to make some folders appear on the top in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, sort

I'd like to have some folders on top e.g. on Windows I had _videos folder which would always appear on top. How do I achieve the same effect in case of Nautilus? It's rarely the case I'd need similar for files but if you know how to do it it also for some files, please drop your hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bookmarks can be added to the left panel in the Nautilus menu in *Bookmarks* > *Add Bookmark* or just pressing Ctrl+D when inside a folder

[image]

If you still want to sort out the folders so that a few are kept always on top you can do so manually by going to *View* > *Arrange Items* > *Manually*, they will keep the desired order.

If you still want to organize by name so that some folders are kept always on top of the order just add a `0` in front of the name, so for i.e. `_videos` would be instead `0videos`.

If you are trying to access your folders as fast as possible another option would be the creation of a quicklist for the Unity launcher, instructions can be found here

- https://askubuntu.com/a/35526/25863

[image]

Comment: Bookmarks are great and I use them but I specifically asked about the trick because there are situations I make use of it aside from bookmarks. The trick with 0's works and I can mark this question as answered but I was just hoping for less visible character. If there are no other character that will do the trick then fine. One more thing. The View > Arrange items > Manually is not available in the List view, the most commonly used by me.

Comment: OK, thanks Bruno! I'm marking this q as answered but please do supplement the answer (anyone) if you know other characters that would push a folder to the top in name-sorted view.

Answer (score 3):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences sort-directories-first true
```

Comment: Improve your answer. Describe precisely what is being done.

Comment: This is handy, because on Debian there seems to be no menu in Nautilus!