# How to get Launcher to show All Instances of an Application

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/961977) was fixed shorty after 12.04 was released.

Well, I liked the old behaviour, especially showing ALL instances of an application on ALL desktops when doubleclicking the launcher icon.

How do I get that functionality back?

Comment: You mean application grouping? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/105400/how-to-disable-the-grouping-of-windows-on-the-launcher

Comment: Thanks to Eddie Dunn for his comment to the bug fix. I hope someone will work on this item before 12.10 gets released.

Comment: This unanswered 5+ year old question is about Ubuntu 12.04. OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years and appears to have lost interest. VTC as `not reproducible`.