# Is it possible to disable launcher grouping in unity?

Tags: unity, launcher, docky, awn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable the grouping of windows on the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105400/how-to-disable-the-grouping-of-windows-on-the-launcher)

I am almost used to working with Unity but the launcher grouping is really bugging me. I just want to be able to open a specific window with ONE click. Currently all instances of an application are grouped under one icon. 
If that's not possible in Unity perhaps there is a dock bar alternative that offers the feature I require. Sadly I have been unable to discover if AWN, Docky or any other dock bar offers this.

Comment: See similar question:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/105400/how-to-disable-the-grouping-of-windows-on-the-launcher