# How to disable the grouping of windows on the launcher Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, launcher, 20.04

There is a similar question about how on Ubuntu unity: [to disable the grouping of windows on the launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105400). If I recall, this can be [done in Lubuntu 18.04](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZCMSOBDIBE).

My question is, how to disable window grouping in the Lubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Right-click on an empty space in your panel.
- Choose *Manage Widgets*.
- Click on *Task Manager (taskbar)* and then on the cog wheel icon (⚙) in the right column.
- In the window that appears, enable/disable *Window Grouping*.

[image: Grouping icons]

Comment: can't launch configure panel ...