# Unable to install DIA on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-center, software-installation

I tried to install **DIA** from the **Software Center** and from the **Terminal** (dia and dia-gnome), but it didn't seem to work. I couldn't find DIA in the **Application Menu** and I also couldn't find it by searching.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Dia cannot be found in the application centre. You have to launch by typing the command `dia` from the terminal or from Alt+F2.

I think this is a bug in 13.04.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works, but it is very impractical. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @damdimdum For the meantime you can create a custom application launcher for the Unity sidebar, have a look at this question & answer - http://askubuntu.com/questions/137154/how-does-one-recreate-a-custom-application-launcher-that-takes-command-line-synt

Answer (score -1):

> Dia is an editor for diagrams, graphs, charts etc. There is support
>   for UML static structure diagrams (class diagrams),
>   Entity-Relationship diagrams, network diagrams and much more. Diagrams
>   can be exported to postscript and many other formats.

This package contains the GNOME version of Dia.

To install [**Dia-Gnome** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/dia-gnome/)

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/dia-gnome/)</sup>

Comment: Already tried this

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu 13.10 May 2015:

[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.original

sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

apt-get update

apt-get install dia
```

Comment: if you copy, then at least properly